# RegEx to select everything between two characters?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that selects everything between two characters.

For example, when the regex encounters a `'§'` I want it to select everything after the `'§'` sign, up until the point that the regex encounters a `';'`. I tried with a lookbehind and lookahead, but they don't really do the trick.

So for example `" § 1-2 bla; "` should return `" 1-2 bla"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please specify the technology in which you are working, as regex has many "flavours" with slightly different syntaxes and capabilities.

Comment: Wait, I missed this first time around... "I tried with a lookbehind and lookahead, but they don't really do the trick." -- why not? what went wrong? Is this JavaScript?

Comment: Because I'm new to RegEx and couldn't really figure it out.. It's RegEx in Actionscript 3, and it does really weird things from time to time :) thanks for your answers everyone, I kind of got things working !

Answer (score 72):

How about

```
"§([^;]*);"
```

The selected characters between the `§` and `;` are available as match group 1.

Comment: This worked for me. But out of curiosity, it also worked without the trailing semi-colon. Why is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, the trailing semi-colon isn't required. Works fine without that too.

Comment: If using in VSCode, remove the trailing semi-colon and the quotes

Answer (score 45):

Use this regex

```
(?<=§).*?(?=;)
```

Comment: Not compatible with JavaScript

Comment: It is compatible with ECMAScript 2018 and newer. See a [related thread about matching a string between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970).

Comment: This works for my case for strings like `"_Åä³¢±Í¸¶°³"` between two quotes while the other answers don't.

Answer (score 20):

For a simple case this should do:

```
§(.*);
```

It might need to be modified if you don't want to allow nesting:

```
§(.*?);
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct - the `.*` is greedy, so the expression will match upto the *last* `;` encountered, not the first one.

Comment: @Peter: it might not be the issue for OP, and it might be what OP actually wants.

Comment: Well based on "up until the point that the regex encounters a ';'" -- I take that to mean it *shouldn't* be greedy.

Comment: @Peter: well based on given example it doesn't matter if quantifier is greedy or not.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to clean out some extraneous decimal values.

Answer (score 11):

If you have multiple § (char example) use : `§([^§]*)§`

It will ignore everything between two §  and only take what's between the 2 special char, so if you have something like `§What§ kind of §bear§ is best`, it will output: `§what§ , §bear§`

What happening? lets dissect the expression § then ([^§]*) then §

1. 1- match § char
2. 2- match anything but § `[^§]` 0 or more times `*`
3. match § char

Hope it helps !