# Get string between two strings in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like:

```
"super example of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string"
```

I want to just keep the string which is between `"key : "` and `" - "`.  How can I do that?  Must I use a Regex or can I do it in another way?

Comment: use `substring` and `indexof`

Comment: Get the string after a particular string in a string and before another specific string which is also contained in the string where the former string is in ..

Comment: Are you still trying to decide which answer to select?

Answer (score 254):

Perhaps, a good way is just to cut out a *substring*:

```
String St = "super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";

int pFrom = St.IndexOf("key : ") + "key : ".Length;
int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(" - ");

String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

Answer (score 49):

```
string input = "super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"key : (.+?)-").Groups[1].Value;
```

or with just string operations

```
var start = input.IndexOf("key : ") + 6;
var match2 = input.Substring(start, input.IndexOf("-") - start);
```

Answer (score 35):

You can do it without regex

```
 input.Split(new string[] {"key :"},StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
      .Split('-')[0]
      .Trim();
```

Comment: This would create multiple unneeded strings in memory. Don't use this if you care about memory.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the way how i can do that

```
   public string Between(string STR , string FirstString, string LastString)
    {       
        string FinalString;     
        int Pos1 = STR.IndexOf(FirstString) + FirstString.Length;
        int Pos2 = STR.IndexOf(LastString);
        FinalString = STR.Substring(Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1);
        return FinalString;
    }
```

Comment: This is the one I ended up using after fixing it for many things. Bug: Pos2 should be STR.IndexOf(LastString, Pos1) in order to start at Pos1. Further checks for 0 Pos values are needed.

Answer (score 19):

Depending on how robust/flexible you want your implementation to be, this can actually be a bit tricky. Here's the implementation I use:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// takes a substring between two anchor strings (or the end of the string if that anchor is null)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="this">a string</param>
    /// <param name="from">an optional string to search after</param>
    /// <param name="until">an optional string to search before</param>
    /// <param name="comparison">an optional comparison for the search</param>
    /// <returns>a substring based on the search</returns>
    public static string Substring(this string @this, string from = null, string until = null, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    {
        var fromLength = (from ?? string.Empty).Length;
        var startIndex = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) 
            ? @this.IndexOf(from, comparison) + fromLength
            : 0;

        if (startIndex < fromLength) { throw new ArgumentException("from: Failed to find an instance of the first anchor"); }

            var endIndex = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(until) 
            ? @this.IndexOf(until, startIndex, comparison) 
            : @this.Length;

        if (endIndex < 0) { throw new ArgumentException("until: Failed to find an instance of the last anchor"); }

        var subString = @this.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        return subString;
    }
}

// usage:
var between = "a - to keep x more stuff".Substring(from: "-", until: "x");
// returns " to keep "
```

Comment: I used your code, but I found a small bug when at
@this.IndexOf(until, startIndex + fromLength, comparison) 
from strings like „AB” where A is from and B is until, so I removed + fromLength.
I haven't tested it deeply though

Comment: @AdrianIftode: good call. This was definitely a bug. It makes sense to start the search for the second anchor at startIndex, since that's already past the end of the first anchor. I've fixed the code here.

Comment: `InvariantCulture` isn't working with Windows Universal Apps. Is there any way to remove it with keeping the functionality of your class? @ChaseMedallion

Comment: @Leon: you should be able to rip out all the culture-related stuff and .NET will just use the current culture for the indexOf operation. I'm not familiar with Windows Universal Apps, though, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 18):

I think this works:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String text = "One=1,Two=2,ThreeFour=34";

        Console.WriteLine(betweenStrings(text, "One=", ",")); // 1
        Console.WriteLine(betweenStrings(text, "Two=", ",")); // 2
        Console.WriteLine(betweenStrings(text, "ThreeFour=", "")); // 34

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static String betweenStrings(String text, String start, String end)
    {
        int p1 = text.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
        int p2 = text.IndexOf(end, p1);

        if (end == "") return (text.Substring(p1));
        else return text.Substring(p1, p2 - p1);                      
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

A working LINQ solution:

```
string str = "super example of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";
string res = new string(str.SkipWhile(c => c != ':')
                           .Skip(1)
                           .TakeWhile(c => c != '-')
                           .ToArray()).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(res); // text I want to keep
```

Comment: Does this works for single-character placeholders only?

Comment: its only for single characters, is not what OP asked for, should be downvoted

Answer (score 11):

Regex is overkill here.

You *could* use `string.Split` with the overload that takes a `string[]` for the delimiters but that would *also* be overkill.

Look at [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) - the former to get parts of a string given and index and a length and the second for finding indexed of inner strings/characters.

Comment: It's not overkill... in fact I would say Substring and IndexOf are underkill. I'd say that string.Split is about right. Regex is overkill.

Comment: The point of it being overkill or under-kill is moot, because the answer fulfills the poster's request of doing it another way than Regex.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: it also fails if there is a " - " before the " key : ".  Substring is spot on.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - I believe he is talking about `string.Split`.

Answer (score 9):

In C# 8.0 and above, you can use the range operator `..` as in

```
var s = "header-THE_TARGET_STRING.7z";
var from = s.IndexOf("-") + "-".Length;
var to = s.IndexOf(".7z");
var versionString = s[from..to];  // THE_TARGET_STRING
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) for details.

Comment: I like the short hand method in C# 8 and above!

Answer (score 7):

or, with a regex.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var value =
    Regex.Match(
        "super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string",
        "key : (.*) - ")
    .Groups[1].Value;
```

with a [running example](http://ideone.com/yVGPTV).

You can decide if its overkill.

### or

as an under validated extension method

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var value =
                "super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string"
                    .Between(
                        "key : ",
                        " - ");

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    static string Between(this string source, string left, string right)
    {
        return Regex.Match(
                source,
                string.Format("{0}(.*){1}", left, right))
            .Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when the string contains '-'
 ex: "Equipment=1,ExternalAntenna=1-1-2,AuxPlugInUnit=2,".Between("ExternalAntenna=",",")

returns "1-1-2,AuxPlugInUnit=2"

this answer below was able to handle my case
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794506/193974

Answer (score 7):

I used the code snippet from Vijay Singh Rana which basically does the job. But it causes problems if the `firstString` does already contain the `lastString`. What I wanted was extracting a access_token from a JSON Response (no JSON Parser loaded). My `firstString` was `\"access_token\": \"` and my `lastString` was `\"`. I ended up with a little modification

```
string Between(string str, string firstString, string lastString)
{    
    int pos1 = str.IndexOf(firstString) + firstString.Length;
    int pos2 = str.Substring(pos1).IndexOf(lastString);
    return str.Substring(pos1, pos2);
}
```

Comment: There is redundancy. pos1 was added to pos2, and then substracted from pos2.

Answer (score 6):

```
 string str="super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";
        int startIndex = str.IndexOf("key") + "key".Length;
        int endIndex = str.IndexOf("-");
        string newString = str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Comment: Your code would result in the colon being returned at the beginning of the newString.

Answer (score 6):

Since the `:` and the `-` are unique you could use:

```
string input;
string output;
input = "super example of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";
output = input.Split(new char[] { ':', '-' })[1];
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything meaningful to the already big amount of existing answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the extension method below:

```
public static string GetStringBetween(this string token, string first, string second)
    {            
        if (!token.Contains(first)) return "";

        var afterFirst = token.Split(new[] { first }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

        if (!afterFirst.Contains(second)) return "";

        var result = afterFirst.Split(new[] { second }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

        return result;
    }
```

Usage is:

```
var token = "super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";
var keyValue = token.GetStringBetween("key : ", " - ");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=key :)(.+?)(?=-)");
```

This returns only the value(s) between "key :" and the following occurance of "-"

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a 1 line solution, this is it:

```
s.Substring(s.IndexOf("eT") + "eT".Length).Split("97".ToCharArray()).First()
```

The whole 1 line solution, with `System.Linq`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class OneLiner
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "TextHereTisImortant973End"; //Between "eT" and "97"
        Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("eT") + "eT".Length)
                           .Split("97".ToCharArray()).First());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  private string gettxtbettwen(string txt, string first, string last)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txt);
        int pos1 = txt.IndexOf(first)  + first.Length;
        int len = (txt.Length ) - pos1;

        string reminder = txt.Substring(pos1, len);


        int pos2 = reminder.IndexOf(last) - last.Length +1;


       



        return reminder.Substring(0, pos2); 



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When questions are stated in terms of a single example ambiguities are inevitably present. This question is no exception.

For the example given in the question the desired string is clear:

```
super example of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, this string is but an example of strings and boundary strings for which certain substrings are to be identified. I will consider a generic string with generic boundary strings, represented as follows.

```
abc FF def PP ghi,PP jkl,FF mno PP pqr FF,stu FF vwx,PP yza
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

`PP` is the *preceding string*, `FF` is the following string and the party hats indicate which substrings are to be matched. (In the example given in the question `key :`  is the preceding string and `-` is the following string.) I have assumed that `PP` and `FF` are preceded and followed by word boundaries (so that `PPA` and `FF8` are not matched).

My assumptions, as reflected by the party hats, are as follows:

- The first substring `PP` may be preceded by one (or more) `FF` substrings, which, if present, are disregarded;
- If `PP` is followed by one or more `PP`s before `FF` is encountered, the following `PP`s are part of the substring between the preceding and following strings;
- If `PP` is followed by one or more `FF`s before a `PP` is encounter, the first `FF` following `PP` is considered to be the following string.

Note that many of the answers here deal with only strings of the form

```
abc PP def FF ghi
      ^^^^^
```

or

```
abc PP def FF ghi PP jkl FF mno
      ^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

One may use a regular expression, code constructs, or a combination of the two to identify the substrings of interest. I make no judgement as to which approach is best. I will only present the following regular expression that will match the substrings of interest.

```
(?<=\bPP\b)(?:(?!\bFF\b).)*(?=\bFF\b)
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/9jgHaS/1/)<sup>1</sup>

I tested this with the PCRE (PHP) regex engine, but as the regex is not at all exotic, I am sure it will work with the .NET regex engine (which is very robust).

The regex engine performs the following operations:

```
(?<=          : begin a positive lookbehind
  \bPP\b      : match 'PP'
)             : end positive lookbehind
(?:           : begin a non-capture group
  (?!         : begin a negative lookahead
    \bFF\b    : match 'FF'
  )           : end negative lookahead
  .           : match any character
)             : end non-capture group
*             : execute non-capture group 0+ times
(?=           : begin positive lookahead
   \bFF\b     : match 'FF'
)             : end positive lookahead
```

This technique, of matching one character at a time, following the preceding string, until the character is `F` and is followed by `F` (or more generally, the character beings the string that constitutes the following string), is called [Tempered Greedy Token Solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Naturally, the regex would have to be modified (if possible) if the assumptions I set out above are changed.

<sup>1. Move the cursor around for detailed explanations.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For get string between string's, I'm using this method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets currently string between
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="word">Currently string</param>
    /// <param name="start">String left</param>
    /// <param name="end">String right</param>
    /// <returns>String between start and end</returns>
    /// <example>The string "value (4815162342)" use Between("(",")") generates in method: "4815162342"</example>
    public static string Between(this string word, string start, string end)
    {
        if (start.Equals(end))
            throw new ArgumentException("Start string can't equals a end string.");

        int startIndex = word.LastIndexOf(start) + 1;
        int endIndex = word.LastIndexOf(end) - 1 - word.LastIndexOf(start);

        return word.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about the string has multiple marks such as a GS1 string like "(01)1234567890128(10)abcdefghij"? I want to get all AIs (in thus case 01 and 10).

Comment: In these cases I indicate to you to found a solution more completely, as Regex, you can implement a method as this 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript'.
But careful, if you wanna found values between '(' and ')', you must get three responses, that is '01', '02' and '01)1234567890128(1'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle *multiple occurrences* of substring pairs, it won't be easy without RegEx:

```
Regex.Matches(input ?? String.Empty, "(?=key : )(.*)(?<= - )", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

> - `input ?? String.Empty` avoids argument null exception
> - `?=` keeps 1st substring and `?<=` keeps 2nd substring
> - `RegexOptions.Singleline` allows newline between substring pair

---

If order & occurrence count of substrings doesn't matter, this quick & dirty one may be an option:

```
var parts = input?.Split(new string[] { "key : ", " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string result = parts?.Length >= 3 ? result[1] : input;
```

At least it avoids most exceptions, by returning the original string if none/single substring match.

Answer (score 0):

You already have some good answers and I realize the code I am providing is far from the most efficient and clean. However, I thought it might be useful for educational purposes. We can use pre-built classes and libraries all day long. But without understanding the inner-workings, we are simply mimicking and repeating and will never learn anything. This code works and is more basic or "virgin" than some of the others:

```
char startDelimiter = ':';
char endDelimiter = '-';

Boolean collect = false;

string parsedString = "";

foreach (char c in originalString)
{
    if (c == startDelimiter)
         collect = true;

    if (c == endDelimiter)
         collect = false;

    if (collect == true && c != startDelimiter)
         parsedString += c;
}
```

You end up with your desired string assigned to the parsedString variable. Keep in mind that it will also capture proceeding and preceding spaces. Remember that a string is simply an array of characters that can be manipulated like other arrays with indices etc.

Take care.

Comment: This is the best algorithm although the worst in string creation. All the answers provided that are not regex-only are trigger-happy at creating strings but this one is the worst of all in that sense. If you had just captured the beginning an end of the string to capture and used ''string.Substring'' to extract it, it would be perfect.

Comment: I agree. As I mentioned, it is far from efficient. I wouldn't recommend using this algorithm. It is simply ""dumbing it down" so he can understand strings at a lower level. If he simply wants to get the job done, he already had answers that would achieve that.

Comment: I understood that. I was just pointing out its strong and week points.
Although, to answer the original question it requires a bit more as it need to match a string boundaries and not just character boundaries. But the idea is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I  always say nothing is impossible:

```
string value =  "super exemple of string key : text I want to keep - end of my string";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(key \: (.*?) _ )");
Match match = regex.Match(value);
if (match.Success)
{
    Messagebox.Show(match.Value);
}
```

> Remeber that should add reference of System.Text.RegularExpressions

Hope That I Helped.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
private static string Between(string text, string from, string to)
{
    return text[(text.IndexOf(from)+from.Length)..text.IndexOf(to, text.IndexOf(from))];
}
```

Comment: As noted in another prior answer this is c# 8+ 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58016957/125981

Answer (score 0):

```
getStringBetween(startStr, endStr, fullStr) {
    string startIndex = fullStr.indexOf(startStr);
    string endIndex= fullStr.indexOf(endStr);
    return fullStr.substring(startIndex + startStr.length, endIndex);
}
```

Comment: @KiranAmadipudi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is;

```
 /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line"></param>
    /// <param name="begin_tag"></param>
    /// <param name="end_tag"></param>
    /// <param name="lastIndexOfEndTag"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string getBetween(string line, string begin_tag, string end_tag, bool lastIndexOfEndTag = false, bool returnNullIfTagsNotExists = false)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(begin_tag) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(end_tag))
        {
            //          1         2         3         4         5         6         7
            //0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
            //StdErrorData:   Duration: 01:59:54.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 557 kb/s
            int startIndex = line.IndexOf(begin_tag);
            if (startIndex >= 0)
            {
                startIndex += begin_tag.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                if (returnNullIfTagsNotExists)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            int endIndex = lastIndexOfEndTag ?
                line.LastIndexOf(end_tag, startIndex)
                : line.IndexOf(end_tag, startIndex);
            if (endIndex > startIndex)
            {
                return line.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                if (returnNullIfTagsNotExists)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return line.Substring(startIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Test;

```
string r = getBetween("StdErrorData:   Duration: 01:59:54.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 557 kb/s", "Duration:", ",");
Console.WriteLine($"<{r}>");
//< 01:59:54.88>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extension method in case anyone interested in keeping the start and end text as well.

```
public static string SubstringBetween(this string text, string start, string end, bool keepStartEndText = false)
    {
        var startIndex = text.IndexOf(start);
        var endIndex = text.LastIndexOf(end);

        if (keepStartEndText)
            return text.Substring(startIndex, (endIndex + end.Length) - startIndex);
        else
            return text.Substring(startIndex + start.Length, endIndex - (startIndex + start.Length));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string ExtractBetweenTwoStrings(string FullText, string StartString, string EndString, bool IncludeStartString, bool IncludeEndString)
    {
        try { int Pos1 = FullText.IndexOf(StartString) + StartString.Length; int Pos2 = FullText.IndexOf(EndString, Pos1); return ((IncludeStartString) ? StartString : "") 
                + FullText.Substring(Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1) + ((IncludeEndString) ? EndString : ""); } catch (Exception ex) { return ex.ToString(); } //return ""; }
    }
```

credit to: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-extract-a-string-lies-between-two-strings-in-c-sharpnet1