# How can i extract a text from string variable using regex?

Tags: c#, .net

```
for (int i = 0; i < lockedThreads.Count; i++)
{
    string link = lockedThreads[i];
}
```

link contains:

> `<a href="http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=111536&forum=scoops1"><b>`

I need to get only:

> `http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=111536&forum=scoops1`

Each time the link is a different one and each time i need to get the link.

So in the end for example string t

Comment: [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: As mentioned before by Syase. HtmlAgilityPack is a versatile tool that can help you with a lot of html parsing problems.

Comment: Please keep in mind that regexp is fine for a quick and dirty approach and if you are absolutely sure the form of the tag you are reading will never change; however websites do change quite frequently or at least you must assume they do.
That aside I would just like to mention that [HTML is no regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/2186023)

Answer (score -3):

The easy way is

```
var arr=link.Split('"');
var neededPart=arr[1];
```

Or You can look here [Get string between two strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string)

Comment: and what if the tag also contains style or class for example? `<a style="...." class="..."`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste than use another way. I inserted link in answer. You can use IndexOf

Comment: The point of my question was, can you really rely on the tag being always formed the way it was shown by OP? And in most cases the answer to that would be NO.