# How do I remove url from text

Tags: c#

I have this sample texts like

```
EA SPORTS UFC  (Microsoft Xbox One, 2014) $40.00 via eBay http://t.co/Wpwj0R1EQm Tibet snake.... http://t.co/yPZXvNnugL
```

How do I remove urls http://t.co/Wpwj0R1EQm, http://t.co/yPZXvNnugL etc from text. I need to perform sentiment analysis and want clean words.

I am able to get rid of bad characters using simple regex.

The pattern is to remove http://t.co/{Whatever-first-word}

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of everything after https?
Because then it is a simple regex.
If not how are you going to determine when to stop? i.e
`something I want something I want https://somethingIdontwant something I want` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular Expressions are your friend.

Simplifying your requirement to be remove all URLS in a given string. If we accept that a URL is anything that starts with http and ends with a space (URLs cannot contain spaces) then something like the follow should suffice. This regex finds any string that starts with http (Will also catch https) and ends in a space and replaces it with an empty string

```
string text = "EA SPORTS UFC  (Microsoft Xbox One, 2014) $40.00 via eBay http://t.co/Wpwj0R1EQm Tibet snake.... http://t.co/yPZXvNnugL";

string cleanedText = Regex.Replace(text, @"http[^\s]+", "");

//cleanedText is now "EA SPORTS UFC  (Microsoft Xbox One, 2014) $40.00 via eBay  Tibet snake.... "
```

Answer (score 3):

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"((http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)", "");
```

The pattern above will match a URL like you want, for example

```
http://this.com/ah.aspx?id=1
```

in:

```
this is a url http://this.com/ah.aspx?id=1 sdfsdf
```

You can see this in action in a [regex fiddle](http://regexr.com/2vtcc) for it.

Comment: A little explanation for such a lengthy regex is in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253735/2577248

Step1. sub = Find substring between "http://" and " " (white space)

Step2. Replace "http://" + sub with @"";

Step3. Repeat util original string does not contain any "http://t.co/any"

```
string str = @"EA SPORTS UFC  (Microsoft Xbox One, 2014) $40.00 via eBay http://t.co/Wpwj0R1EQm Tibet snake.... http://t.co/yPZXvNnugL" + " ";

while(str.Contains("http://")){
    string removedStr = str.Substring("http://", @" ");
    str = str.Replace("http://" + removedStr , @"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

And I would try this patten:
`var regex_url_pattern = @"_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS"`

Combined:

`string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex_url_pattern, "");`