# Parse a parameter inside URL using C#

Tags: c#, html, url, browser

Let's say that I have url like `http://google.com/index.php?first=asd&second=mnb&third=lkj`

How can I get second value (`mnb`) using c#?

Comment: Windows Forms or Web Forms? Post some code.

Comment: or asp.net....? Whatever the answer is, you should really just Google something this basic. If you have code that isn't working, you should show it and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this MVC application?

Comment: Windows Forms, I do not have any code for this moment

Comment: there is a `URI` class that you can look at along with how to determine the value based on the `QueryString`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ParseQueryString` method from `System.Web.HttpUtility` class.

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri("http://google.com/index.php?first=asd&second=mnb&third=lkj");
string first= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(targetUri.Query).Get("first");
string second= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(targetUri.Query).Get("second");
```

Find more here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For simple string parsing you can use an extension method:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var value = "url".Between("second=", "&third");
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    static string Between(this string source, string left, string right)
    {
        return Regex.Match(
                source,
                string.Format("{0}(.*){1}", left, right))
            .Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

However, approaches with URL parsing suggested in comments are almost certain better.

Source: [Get string between two strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String URL = "http://google.com/index.php?first=asd&second=mnb&third=lkj";

UriBuilder UrlThing = new UriBuilder(URL);

System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Args =  HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(UrlThing.Query);

String Second = Args["Second"];
```