# Get a special, signed part of a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
blabla random-string-I-dont-need blabla
SPECIALSTRING
the-string-I-need
STRINGSPECIAL
blabla other-string-I-dont-need blabla
SPECIALSTRING
the-string-I-need
STRINGSPECIAL
//etc, I have a very long file with this 'pattern' repeated
```

What I need out of this string are the

```
SPECIALSTRING
the-string-I-need
STRINGSPECIAL
```

parts as many times it appears in the string - **the-string-I-need** is always different, but **specialstring** and **stringspecial** are always the same - and different from each other.

(Just note, that I can't count on new line characters, I just added them here to give you a better vision.)

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What result you expect is it a plain `string` or `string[]` ?

Comment: I tried to find substrings, but got confused with take() and remove() methods.

Comment: @Fabjan I will write it to a file, so it doesn't matter (I guess?)

Comment: this must be a duplicate

Comment: Will the specialstring allways be on its own line?

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string

Comment: @WilliamMoore no, we don't know it for sure; we don't know anything about the string, only about the special strings indicating the string we need

Comment: @WilliamMoore and also is important, that I may have hundreds of these strings I need. so I guess I will need a while() somewhere..?