# update change replace chars textbox c# from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, replace, textbox

I have a textbox where I am able to find and replace things with a click on the button, but it does not change the textbox itself. 
Below is the code I'm using to change some stuff to my need:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var abc = textBox1.Text.Between("abc", "&");
    var def = textBox1.Text.Between("def", "&");
    var ghi = textBox1.Text.Between("ghi", "&");
    var jkl = textBox1.Text.Between("jkl", "&");
    var test = abc.Replace("" + abc + "", "any");
    var test1 = def.Replace("" + def + "", "any");
    var test2 = ghi.Replace("" + ghi + "", "any");
    var test3 = jkl.Replace("" + jkl + "", "any");
}
```

now I'm using that with a button but when I fire up the button it does not change anything in my textbox.

I've been googling around offcourse and found `this.textBox1.Refresh();`
but this also doens't change anything.

All help would be great, thanks in advance..

Comment: Strings are immutable. So if you want textboxes to show changed/replaced values, you have to assign those changed values back to `Textbox.Text`.

Comment: ok I understand but it is a Textbox with multiple lines and characters, when I do what you said it only printsout textBox1.Text = test;

Comment: Well you need to concatenate all results into one string and assign that one to `TextBox.Text`. Something along those lines `TextBox1.Text = string.Concat(new[] {test, test1, test2, test3});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assigned the changed `string` back to your `textBox1`. Something like this.

Edit: assuming what you mean by in between is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string)

```
private string findBetweenMethod(string text, string start, string end){
    string betweenText = text;
    .... //process
    return betweenText;
}

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var abc = findBetweenMethod(textBox1.Text,"abc", "&"); //find what to change
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(abc, "any"); //change it, assign it back to the textBox1
    var def = findBetweenMethod(textBox1.Text,"def", "&"); 
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(def, "any");
    var ghi = findBetweenMethod(textBox1.Text,"ghi", "&"); 
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(ghi, "any");
    var jkl = findBetweenMethod(textBox1.Text,"jkl", "&"); 
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(jkl, "any");
}
```

Note: beware of your text pattern though. The above method is assuming clean, singular, pattern. That is, what you really want is in between "abc" and "&" (and so on) and there is no such pattern repeated elsewhere besides the intended one.

But the basic idea here is to assigned back the changed `string` to the `textBox1`, as explained by @sharpstudent and others

Comment: What is `Between` method? Just curious :)

Comment: I needed to change some parameters Between certain parameters ;) @sharpstudent

Comment: @sharpstudent you are right, it is not built-in. I edited my answer according to what I think is `Between` (I put the reference article)