# How to read the text between two string from a text file using c#?

Tags: c#

**My Text File:**

```
   Users of Yamaha:  (Total of 1 bike issued;  Total of 1 bike in use)
        bike details
        1001  Dinesh , start Fri 1/13 8:55
   Users of Hero:  (Total of 1 bike issued;  Total of 1 bike in use)
        bike details
        1002  Monika, start Fri 1/13 9:55
   Users of Honda:  (Total of 2 bike issued;  Total of 1 bike in use)
        bike details
        1003  Monikadinesh, start Fri 1/13 5:55
```

Here I want to Extract the line between two strings.Here I want to Append the line into a string. I want to extract the Line between two  **Users of**.

My Extracted String will be like this  :

```
//**The content lie between two users of** 
    (Total of 1 bike issued;  Total of 1 bike in use)Append it in multi array.
                bike details
                1001  Dinesh , start Fri 1/13 8:55
```

I don't know how to Solve my problem.Help me to solve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get string between two strings in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at `String.Split`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

It could look like this: `string[] split = myString.Split(new string[] { "Users of" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

than remove everything to the `:` with this `split[0].Substring(split[0].IndexOf(":") + 3)`