# Count tabs between words in a string C#

Tags: c#, delimiter

I need to count the number of tabs between words in the string

```
string s = "DATE\t\t\tVERSION\t\tAUTHOR\t\t\t\t\tCOMMENTS";


int TabsDateVersion;     //number of tabs between "Date" and "Version"
int TabsVersionAuthor;   //number of tabs between "Version" and "Author"
int tabsAuthorComments;  //number of tabs between "Author" and "Comments"
```

Note: words are **only** separated by one or more tabs.

Any idea how to do this in C#, so I have 3 different counts?

Comment: can i ask why u need to count the tabs? - if u want for example a textfile where the words are formatted like a table, there are more simplier solutions

Comment: Are they actually tab characters (`\t`) or are they space characters like in your example?

Comment: @IanH. They are only tab characters between the words

Comment: do you know how to use the function [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) ? you would simply need to count the number of characters in each position of the returned array. But you really should consider to post at least one own attempt to solve this problem. Have you tried at least using a for-loop?

Comment: @Raizzen. It is from an XML-file and I am stuck to it

Comment: What output do you expect? The total number of tabs (10) or an array of the count between words in a string (3, 2, 5)?

Comment: @Middas array of the count between words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string by keywords then count it.

```
 string s = "DATE\t\t\tVERSION\t\tAUTHOR\t\t\tCOMMENTS";
 string[] list = s.Split(new string[] { "DATE", "VERSION", "COMMENTS", "AUTHOR" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
 int TabsDateVersion = list[1].Count(x => x == '\t');     
 int TabsVersionAuthor = list[2].Count(x => x == '\t');
 int tabsAuthorComments = list[3].Count(x => x == '\t');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string HAS tabs (and not 4 spaces rapresenting the tab) you can easily count using LINQ

```
var s = "DATE,      VERSION             AUTHOR      COMMENTS";

Console.WriteLine(CountTabs(s,"DATE","VERSION"));
Console.WriteLine(CountTabs(s,"VERSION","AUTHOR"));
Console.WriteLine(CountTabs(s,"AUTHOR","COMMENTS"));

public static int CountTabs(string source, string fromVal, string toVal)
{
    int startIdx = source.IndexOf(fromVal);
    int endIdx = source.IndexOf(toVal);

    return source.Skip(startIdx).Take(endIdx - startIdx).Count(c => c == '\t');
}
```

> Note: No error handling if `fromVal` and `toVal` is not part of `source`.

Comment: how do you distinguish afterwards which tabs belongs to which gap between the words?

Comment: @Sayse you're right, this gives only the total numbers of tabs

Comment: @BertAR I am changing this

Comment: @Sayse Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using information on how to get text between words from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string) answer, I wrote a simple function that takes the total `string`, the left word, the right word and the `char` to look for.

```
public int CountCharactersBetweenWords(string totalString, string leftWord, string rightWord, char search)
{
    // Find the indexes of the end of the left and the start of the right word
    int pFrom = totalString.IndexOf(leftWord) + leftWord.Length;
    int pTo = totalString.LastIndexOf(rightWord);

    // Get the substring between the words
    string between = totalString.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

    // Count the characters that are equal with the character to search for
    return between.Count(c => c == search);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
string s = "DATE\t\t\tVERSION\t\tAUTHOR\t\t\t\t\tCOMMENTS";
int count = CountCharactersBetweenWords(s, "DATE", "VERSION", '\t');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a one liner! With regex!

```
Regex.Match("DATE\t\t\tVERSION\t\tAUTHOR\t\t\t\t\tCOMMENTS", 
    "DATE(\\t*)").Groups[1].Length
```

The regex used here is

```
DATE(\t*)
```

It basically looks for `"DATE"` and captures all the tab characters after it and put them all in group 1. You can replace `"DATE"` with `"VERSION"`, `"COMMENTS"` etc.

Remember to add a using directive to `System.Text.RegularExpressions`!