# How to find particular text in a text file

Tags: c#

My input text file looks like on this format

```
Consignee                                  Documnet No
MANULI DA AMAZONIA                         12345678
INDUSTRIA DE EMBALAGENS LTDA AV.            Export Reference
BURITI 3670 BAIRRO DISTRITO                 44444557
INDUSTRIAL 69075-000 MANAUS, AM             555555555
```

1. First i want read Consignee details
2. Second i want to read Doucment No details
3. Export Reference  details

My program is running good

Note: I am facing the  problem is when I am reading a consignee name I want to extract the text line of the consignee details. But here extracting the document no and export reference details also. So here I want to skip the text line of the document no and export reference details  When I am reading consignee Name

My output comes like on  this format.  When I read consignee Name

```
Consingee
MANULI DA AMAZONIA 
INDUSTRIA DE EMBALAGENS LTDA AV 
BURITI 3670 BAIRRO DISTRITO
INDUSTRIAL 69075-000 MANAUS, AM
```

Comment: Please post yoor code here

Comment: My program code

string text=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\text1.txt");
int i = text.IndexOf("Consignee");
string consignee= text.Substring(i+9,110);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\output.txt"Consignee"=+consingee);
console.Writeline("Consignee="+consingee);
console.Read()

Comment: there is hard coded "Consignee" . if you dont want display header "Consignee". just remove header and display consignee value.for.e.g; console.Writeline(consingee);

Comment: i have to read lot of values in a text file so if i remove the header name  how could it possible.

Comment: HI Hazarath Chillara how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code *there*.  Code in comments is unreadable and almost useless.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correct you want to skip the header.  you can try some thing like this

```
stringReader.ReadLine() /// this will read first line  and don't do any processing .header will be skipped

while ((txtline = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{

/// do your processing 
}
```

Comment: there is hard coded "Consignee" . if you dont want display header "Consignee". just remove header and display consignee value.for.e.g; console.Writeline(consingee);

Comment: The problem is on my code  when i read consignee header its reading document no and export reference details. so i don't want to read at the  of time reading consignee details

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should try to split string and convert it to list to get text you are looking. Like :

```
string[] data = str.Split(' ');
// str is your main string
// array data contains all your info splitted in array form so you could get 
// Xth member of array like data[X];
```

Moreover if you know what string will come before or end of your given name then you could easily get text in a string by implementing some methods like : [get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string)

Comment: ofc but i cant understand correctly which part of string you want to extract

Comment: if i read consignee header output shows like this                                       CONSIGNEE                                                                                
MANULI DA AMAZONIA                                                        INDUSTRIA DE EMBALAGENS LTDA AV                                 
BURITI 3670 BAIRRO DISTRITO                                     INDUSTRIAL 69075-000 MANAUS, AM

Comment: I mean what you expect coming from that string ? i mean what you want to get from it

Comment: i want to do first extract all  sub-string,  after extract sub-string i want to store  in sql db

Comment: ha! i appreaciate your speech but i cant post my email publicly :v

Comment: That fine but how to get i solution for this