# Get specific interval using substring

Tags: c#

I have the following string.

```
"<This is my string=NHUYT>"
```

I would like to get words between `"="` and `">"` but I would like to make this generic, not for only this word NHUYT.

Using substring I tried:

```
var line = "<This is my string=NHUYT>"
var index = line.Trim().IndexOf("=");
var lastIndex = line.Trim().IndexOf(">");

var id = line.Substring(index, lastIndex);
```

But I can't do that because `lastIndex` is actually the length, so how can I do this?

> Substring(Int32, Int32)    Retrieves a substring from this instance. The
>   substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified
>   length.

Comment: `but I would to make this generic, not for only this word NHUYT.` what actually do you mean by **generic** ?

Comment: `lastIndex - index`?

Comment: You shouldn´t provide the last **index**, but the **length**, which is `lastIndex - firstIndex`.

Comment: ... although I think you mean `(index + 1, lastIndex - (index + 1))`, else you'll get "=NHUYT". And for consistency you should Trim before Substringing, and / or just trim line in the first place.

Comment: You you describe more what strings may appear? It would be good to better understand the rules of them. Example: Could there be something like "<this is= another string=ABCED>" With another equal in it?

Comment: @er-sho for other word, for example string=BSCHTEGRTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the length by subtracting the first index from the last index. Also if you are going to `Trim()`, do it once in the initial string rather than when finding the `IndexOf`, because when you're doing the substring you're not trimming and the indexes might be off.

```
var line = "<This is my string=NHUYT>".Trim();
var index = line.IndexOf("=") + 1;
var lastIndex = line.IndexOf(">");

var id = line.Substring(index, lastIndex - index);
```

Comment: It should be `index + 1`, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HmeCFx).

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder thanks, edited.

Comment: One can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252672/1275774) that the "key" length needs to be accounted for, in this case the "key" is of length 1, "=".