# Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to write a regular expression which returns a string which is between parentheses. For example: I want to get the string which resides between the strings "(" and ")"

```
I expect five hundred dollars ($500).
```

would return

```
$500
```

Found [Regular expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript)

I don't know how to use '(', ')' in regexp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters, while EXCLUDING the delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu)

Comment: you can use go-oleg's solution below, slightly modified to test for the dollar sign: `var regExp = /\(\$([^)]+)\)/;`

Answer (score 635, accepted):

You need to create a set of escaped (with `\`) parentheses (that match the parentheses) and a group of regular parentheses that create your capturing group:

```js
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec("I expect five hundred dollars ($500).");

//matches[1] contains the value between the parentheses
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Breakdown:

- `\(` : match an opening parentheses
- `(` : begin capturing group
- `[^)]+`: match one or more non `)` characters
- `)` : end capturing group
- `\)` : match closing parentheses

Here is a visual explanation on [RegExplained](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/?pattern=%252F%5C((%5B%5E)%5D%252B)%5C)%252F)

Comment: +1 Nice, worked like a charm. I would like to add you to add this http://tinyurl.com/mog7lr3 in your for a visual explanation.

Comment: What if i require to retrieve between [something]

Comment: This doesn't work if there are parentheses within the parentheses you want to capture.  Such as: "I expect five hundred dollars ($500 (but I know I'll never see that money again))."

Comment: hi i tried getting regex for retuning a value between `-` example `2015-07-023` i want to get `07` i tried `var regExp = /\(([^)]+-)\)/;` but i get null can your clarify?

Comment: `("(some txt )".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/g)[1] === undefined);`. Please clarify.

Comment: This regex works only if matching one instance per sting. Using the global `/g` flag wont work as expected.

Comment: if brackets are changed into double quotes, e.g. "$500", it becomes `/\"([^)]+)\"/` Yes! I did it! thnks.

Comment: Why isn't it the first match? i.e. matches[0]

Comment: @IanWarburton, matches[0] gives you the full string of characters matched '($500)', while matches[1] gives you just what's in the capturing group. Here is some more info on the return value of regExp.match(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: what is the solution if you have multiple strings inside  parentheses like below: 
"I expect (five) hundred dollars ($500)"
let's say I want an array of those special strings.

Comment: @CodeGuru To retrieve between [something] use the regex `/\[(.*?)\]/`

Comment: why /\(.*\)/ not working? and you need that addition of 'capturing group'?

Comment: This is really useful, having access to the full statement, with the brackets, in `matches[0]` and the actual value in `matches[1]` as it means that I can deal with and process `matches[1]` and then remove `matches[0]` from my original string with such a statement as `myString.replace(matches[0], "");`

Comment: how to store this regex as string literal in data store and use it again ? If I do, `regex = new RegExp("/\(([^)]+)\)/", "ig")` 
it's not working

Comment: Can this be modified to retain the parentheses in each match? In other words: `matches[0] === '($500)'`? UPDATE—FIGURED IT OUT: just capture the group outside the term: `/(\([^)]+\))/g`

Answer (score 43):

Try string manipulation:

```
var txt = "I expect five hundred dollars ($500). and new brackets ($600)";
var newTxt = txt.split('(');
for (var i = 1; i < newTxt.length; i++) {
    console.log(newTxt[i].split(')')[0]);
}
```

or regex (*which is somewhat [slow compare to the above](http://jsperf.com/stringvsregex/)*)

```
var txt = "I expect five hundred dollars ($500). and new brackets ($600)";
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;
var matches = txt.match(regExp);
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var str = matches[i];
    console.log(str.substring(1, str.length - 1));
}
```

Comment: Running that jsperf today in Chrome 59.0.3071, the regex was faster by 8%

Answer (score 26):

**Simple solution**

**Notice**: this solution can be used for strings having only single "(" and ")" like string in this question.

```
("I expect five hundred dollars ($500).").match(/\((.*)\)/).pop();
```

[**Online demo (jsfiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/pw0nem88/)

Comment: add optional chaining in case match doesnt exist will return undefined instead of resulting in uncaught exception

("I expect five hundred dollars ($500).").match(/\((.*)\)/)?.pop();

Answer (score 23):

To match a substring inside parentheses excluding any inner parentheses you may use

```
\(([^()]*)\)
```

pattern. See [the **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GfBeUM/1).

In JavaScript, use it like

```
var rx = /\(([^()]*)\)/g;
```

**Pattern details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group 1: a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

To get the whole match, grab Group 0 value, if you need the text inside parentheses, grab Group 1 value.

Most up-to-date JavaScript code demo (using `matchAll`):

```js
const strs = ["I expect five hundred dollars ($500).", "I expect.. :( five hundred dollars ($500)."];
const rx = /\(([^()]*)\)/g;
strs.forEach(x => {
  const matches = [...x.matchAll(rx)];
  console.log( Array.from(matches, m => m[0]) ); // All full match values
  console.log( Array.from(matches, m => m[1]) ); // All Group 1 values
});
```

Legacy JavaScript code demo (ES5 compliant):

```js
var strs = ["I expect five hundred dollars ($500).", "I expect.. :( five hundred dollars ($500)."];
var rx = /\(([^()]*)\)/g;


for (var i=0;i<strs.length;i++) {
  console.log(strs[i]);

  // Grab Group 1 values:
  var res=[], m;
  while(m=rx.exec(strs[i])) {
    res.push(m[1]);
  }
  console.log("Group 1: ", res);

  // Grab whole values
  console.log("Whole matches: ", strs[i].match(rx));
}
```

Comment: This regex is great because it only captures pairs of `()` and their contents, even when side by side`()()`.

Comment: @limitlessloop Since this seems a helpful answer, I also added a new `matchAll` based JavaScript code demo.

Comment: this answer is the best.

Comment: How to include parantheses, can you give an example about that too?

Comment: @postgresnewbie It is already there, `console.log( Array.from(matches, m => m[0]) ); // All full match values`. You do not need the group then, and can use `var rx = /\([^()]*\)/g;`

Answer (score 13):

Ported [Mr_Green's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17780281/942767) to a functional programming style to avoid use of temporary global variables.

```
var matches = string2.split('[')
  .filter(function(v){ return v.indexOf(']') > -1})
  .map( function(value) { 
    return value.split(']')[0]
  })
```

Comment: What I was looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614116/how-to-get-all-sub-strings-inside-a-string-that-starts-with-and-end-with-a-chara?noredirect=1#comment86234810_49614116

Answer (score 8):

Alternative:

```
var str = "I expect five hundred dollars ($500) ($1).";
str.match(/\(.*?\)/g).map(x => x.replace(/[()]/g, ""));
```

```
→ (2) ["$500", "$1"]
```

It is possible to replace brackets with square or curly brackets if you need

Comment: This is broken when `str` has no brackets

Answer (score 6):

For just digits after a currency sign : `\(.+\s*\d+\s*\)` should work

Or `\(.+\)` for anything inside brackets

Comment: This will work for the sample text, however if another `)` appears later in the string like `I expect five hundred dollars ($500). (but I'm going to pay).` the greediness of the `+` will capture a lot more.

Comment: @Denomales So how would you have it capture both instances of those strings. Ideally I am doing something similar but I would like to have:

`($500)` and `(but I'm going to pay)` 

be matched but in two separates matches rather than being considered a single matched item?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: \(.+\) worked for my requirement. Needed to capture stuffs like "Dunhill (Bottle/Packet/Pot/Shot)" and return just "Dunhill"

Answer (score 4):

```js
let str = "Before brackets (Inside brackets) After brackets".replace(/.*\(|\).*/g, '');
console.log(str) // Inside brackets
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "I expect five hundred dollars ($500) ($1).";
var rex = /\$\d+(?=\))/;
alert(rex.exec(str));
```

Will match the first number starting with a $ and followed by ')'. ')' will not be part of the match. The code alerts with the first match.

```
var str = "I expect five hundred dollars ($500) ($1).";
var rex = /\$\d+(?=\))/g;
var matches = str.match(rex);
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
{
    alert(matches[i]);
}
```

This code alerts with all the matches.

References:

search for "?=n"
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

search for "x(?=y)"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
`(?<value>(?<=\().*(?=\)))`

I hope I've helped.