# how to get the value(ID) using javascript substring?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract a string from within a larger string where i need to get the value only inside the brackets.

```
var str = 'ajay kumar (68766)';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var str = 'ajay kumar (68766)';
str = str.slice(str.indexOf('(')+1, str.indexOf(')'));
```

Comment: thanq...
how to store the str (value) in the next text box field?

Comment: if you have a textbox like: `<input type="text" id="box">` you can put the value in that textbox with: `document.getElementById('box').value = str;`

Comment: hmm yes its working...

Comment: @kim.ramesh good! :) Mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: document.getElementById('box').value = str;
how to get it? explain

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regular expression?

```
var str = 'ajay kumar (68766)';
var output = str.replace(/^[\s\S]*?\((\d+)\)[\s\S]*?$/, '$1');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: it just seems to delete the brackets, but the words before the opening bracket are intact.

Comment: @DanielLisik Sorry, I made a mistake. I've corrected the code now.

Comment: @DanielLisik See http://jsfiddle.net/C5NLJ/ for a working JSFiddle.