# Get numeric value of webkit filter property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(".content").css("-webkit-filter")
```

Return :

```
"opacity(0.46) grayscale(0.7)"
```

How can i get only this value : 0.46 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9rf9/)

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var str = regExp.exec("opacity(0.46) grayscale(0.7)");
var modified = str[0].substring(1).slice(0, -1);
console.log(modified);
```

RegExp was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

you could use regex (http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2Yk/):

```
var cssStyle = $(".content").css("-webkit-filter");
var regExp = /opacity\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec(cssStyle);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Fiddle

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjsku/)

```
$(".content").css('opacity')
```