# JavaScript Date receive as object like this trip.Date: "/Date(1426530600000)/"

Tags: javascript

My javascript Date received like this.

trip.Date: "/Date(1426530600000)/"

How can i convert this to Date format

I tried this working:

var dt = new Date(1426530600000); // output: Tue Mar 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Is there any other predefined methods to convert this  "/Date(1426530600000)/"

Comment: There's no predefined way. If new Date(1426530600000), what's the issue in using that only.

Comment: This looks like its a string made for `eval`. Now dont go using eval! The best way for this is to get the numbers out and run it through the Date function yourself. So something like `new Date( parseInt(Date(1426530600000).split("(")[1]) )` should do the trick.

Comment: /Date(1426530600000)/ How can i split the number from this string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example an RegEx expression such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript), then:

```js
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec("/Date(1426530600000)/");  // insert string
alert(new Date(parseInt(matches[1], 10)));           // parseInt() the string
```

A string split is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you create the date correctly. but then you have several methods to represent the date as string.

`.toString()` returns your local date and time

`.toISOString()` returns GMT time in the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.sssZ`

for more see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: /Date(1426530600000)/ How can i split the number from this string

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle with dates:

```
var timestamp = "1426530600000";

//Parse the timestamp to Moment
var dateAsMoment = moment(timestamp);

//parse your date to String (any formats that you need)
dateAsMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Or you can use your `Date` object:

```
var dt = new Date(1426530600000);
var dateAsMoment = moment(dt);
...
```

Edit:
To extract the timestamp from your 'eval' string:

```
//using a regex to get the contents between parenthesis 
var timestamp = "/Date(1426530600000)/".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]
```

Comment: /Date(1426530600000)/ How can i split the number from this string

Comment: @Vicky i updated the answer with one example