# How to track down tab updates using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

i have a webpage where the notifications get updated at the browser tab ,let me take on a live [example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) here the browser tab gets updated with the message count,how can i track down using selenium webdriver

[image]

Comment: It's just a part of a <title> tag. Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Is this possible with Selenium webdriver? it automates only web page rit..

Comment: @saravana nope friend we can handle browser actions too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fire up a **regex** using javascript from selenium script to find the counter you need. You can check before and after state to verify.

```
console.log((/\(([^)]+)\)/).exec(document.title)[1]);
```

If you want to do it using **selenium** and **java**:

```
String title = driver.getTitle();
String counter = title.substring(title.indexOf("(") + 1, title.indexOf(")"));
```

Tested with gmail, title = "Inbox (1) - chandan.nayak@xxxx.com - xxxx Mail" and stackoverflow, title = "(13) JavaScript | xxx"

Ref Links: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744)

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript executor should be sufficient in this case. As @Stanjer mentioned this count has been updated in the *title*. You can also do a simple RegEx filter to get the count only

An example using `Selenium` C# binding:

```
string count = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('title').innerHTML.match('[0-9]+');") as string;
```

It is also important that you keep the focus on the related tab