# I have a string in javascript. I need to pick all strings between "{" and "}"

Tags: javascript

I have a string in javascript. I need to pick all strings between `"{"` and `"}"`.

Example:

```
QUO-{MM/YYYY}-{SERVICEGROUP}
```

Here i need to grab strings between `{}`.

Comment: Okay. Once you've given it a try, if you get stuck, post a question showing what you've tried and asking why it isn't working. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: try using regex.. something like this `{(.*)}` should do.

Comment: can there be escaped `{` and `}` characters inside a `{}` group? Also, how robust do you want your parser to be (e.g. should it crash on `{SERVICEGROUP}}`, ignore the extra `}`, include it…)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

Comment: @sachin, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression `/{(.*?)}/g`:

```
var re = new RegExp('{(.*?)}', 'g');
result = re.exec('QUO-{MM/YYYY}-{SERVICEGROUP}');
```

Will output: `["{MM/YYYY}", "MM/YYYY"]`

**Edit:**

```
'QUO-{MM/YYYY}-{SERVICEGROUP}'.match(/{(.*?)}/g);
```

Will output: `["{MM/YYYY}", "{SERVICEGROUP}"]`

Comment: Nice one. But i need the output as ["{MM/YYYY}","{SERVICEGROUP}"]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @dr.dimitru

Comment: i want to give 10 but my reputation still less than 15. once i reached 15 i will give for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92305/discussion-between-dr-dimitru-and-vaasudev).