# Regex to select text between parentheses with a specific text as target

Tags: regex, target, parentheses

I try to build a Regex to select all text between parentheses with a specific text like  as target.

Something like `(*TARGET*)`. I found this regex here : [Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript) But (2014) and (Format) are select also.

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

-Sample

```
Number 473 (2014) (Format)(not_wanted-text1 TARGET not-wanted_text2).xxx
```

or

```
Number 473 (2014) (Format)(TARGET not-wanted_text2).xxx
```

or

```
Number 473 (2014) (Format)(not-wanted_text2TARGET).xxx
```

-Expected result

```
Number 473 (2014) (Format).xxx
```

Thanks

Comment: Which programing language are you using?

Comment: None, it's for ReNamer Pro. All JS regex work fine with it. Thanks for the layout modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to include the target string surrounded by character classes that exclude the closing parenthesis:

```
\(([^)]*TARGET[^)]*)\)
```

If you only need to replace the match, you don't need the capture group (you can remove it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for.