# How do I get specific value from string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this string

"551230(95.169%)"

I want only numbers from bracket like 95.169.

Comment: is the value always in parentheses and have a percent sign? have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. value is always in parentheses. I tried using split. but its not work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EZ PZ. Just `split` twice:

```js
let a = "551230(95.169%)".split("(")[1].split("%")[0]

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

string is an array, you can always get characters from it

```
var oldstring = "551230(95.169%)"
var newstring = "";

for(i=7;i<14;i++)
{
newstring+=oldstring[i];
}

console.log(newstring);
```

If you don't know the length of the string, you can create a regex pattern to extract the characters between the parentheses.

```
\((.*?)\)
```

would work