# C# - Get All Words Between Chars

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have string:

```
string mystring = "hello(hi,mo,wo,ka)";
```

And i need to get all arguments in brackets.
Like:

```
hi*mo*wo*ka
```

I tried that:

```
string res = "";
string mystring = "hello(hi,mo,wo,ka)";
mystring.Replace("hello", "");
string[] tokens = mystring.Split(',');
string[] tokenz = mystring.Split(')');
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
     res += "*" + " " + s +" ";
}
foreach (string z in tokenz)
{
     res += "*" + " " + z + " ";
}
return res;
```

But that returns all words before ",".

(I need to return between

"(" and ","

"," and ","

"," and ")"

)

Comment: Why you don't use Regex ?

Comment: I asked how to do it.
So i wanted to know how and learn.
im new to Regex.
And that not answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the substring of the non conditional part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325313/get-the-substring-of-the-non-conditional-part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `\\(([^)]+)\\)` regex get the word contain in brackets,then use `Replace` function to let `,` to `*`

```
string res = "hello(hi,mo,wo,ka)";

var regex =  Regex.Match(res, "\\(([^)]+)\\)");
var result = regex.Groups[1].Value.Replace(',','*');
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OHKZ50)

**Result**

```
hi*mo*wo*ka
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I like it!
P.S. that returns it with brackets,like:
    (hi,mo,wo,ka)
but in any way thanks.

Comment: @Qrai Glad to help:)

Answer (score 0):

This way :

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\((.*)\)");
  var result = rgx.Match("hello(hi,mo,wo,ka)");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Split` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) has an override that lets you define multiple delimiter chars:

```
string mystring = "hello(hi,mo,wo,ka)";
var tokens = mystring.Replace("hello", "").Split(new[] { "(",",",")" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```