# find `'('+any number+')'` in string and split JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can i find `'('+any number+')'` in a string to split the string into array like i have this text

`"(1)some words  (2)other words (3)other words (4)other words ...."`and so on

here is what i have tried `someString.split(/[0-9]/)`

result:`"("
 ")some words  ("
 ")other words ("
 ")other words ("
 ")other words"`

this seems to find only numbers from 0 to 9

i need something like `('('+/[0-9]/+')')`

Comment: I think what you'd need most would be to follow a quick regex tutorial before you try to use them. In the meantime, `/\(\d+\)/` might suit your needs

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex on `\d+` or `\(\d+\)`

```js
console.log( 
  "(1)some words  (2)other words (3)other words (4)other words .... (10)end"
  .match(/\d+/g) // or \d{1,}
)
```

Only in brackets using a capturing group:

```js
const re = /\((\d+)\)/g;
while (match = re.exec("(1)some words  (2)other words (3)other number 3 words (4)other words .... (10)end")) {
  console.log(match[1])
}
```

Comment: what about the (  before the number and ) after the number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to actually end up with an array of terms, not numbers, we can try doing a regex split on the pattern `\(\d+\)`:

```js
input = "(1)some words  (2)other words (3)other words (4)other words ....";
terms = input.split(/\(\d+\)/);
terms.shift();
console.log(terms);
```

You have a few problems going on, but as to why your current split is only targeting `0-9`, this is because the regex pattern `[0-9]` just means 0 to 9.  Use `[0-9]+` or `\d+` to target any number of digits.