# How to match repeated patterns with optional spaces between them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make the following extraction from string in JS:

```
'Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)' => ['abc']
'Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc) ' => ['abc']
'Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc) (cde)' => ['abc','cde']
'Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)(cde) (efgh)' => ['abc', 'cde', 'efgh']
```

I need to extract 'tags' in brackets, they may have spaces between them and also the whole string could have space in the end.

I've tried something like `/(\(.*\))(\s?\(.*\))+/`, but it's not enough to collect all the tags. How can I extract all I need having these optional spaces between and after tags?

Comment: What about`\(([^)]+)\)` you can find it here in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should achieve what you require:

```
/(?<=\()\w*(?=\))/g)
```

This pattern roughly translates to:

1. **(?<=()** *Look for a ( and start matching after that character*
2. **\w*** *"Look for zero or more word characters and match those"*
3. **(?=))** *"Look for a ) and stop matching prior to this character"*
4. **/g** *"Apply this pattern matching behavior globally across whole input string"*

Using this pattern with the [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function will result in zero or more strings being returned in an array, where the contents of those strings correspond to the content between parantheiss pairs of your input string:

```js
const pattern = /(?<=\()\w*(?=\))/g;

console.log('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)'.match(pattern));
console.log('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc) '.match(pattern));
console.log('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc) (cde)'.match(pattern));
console.log('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)(cde) (efgh)'.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may match the consecutive parenthesized  substrings and then split the result:

```js
var s = 'Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)(cde) (efgh)';
var m = s.match(/\([^()]*\)(?:\s*\([^()]*\))*/) || [""];
console.log(m[0].replace(/^\(|\)$/g, '').split(/\)\s*\(/));
```

The `\([^()]*\)(?:\s*\([^()]*\))*` [pattern will match](https://regex101.com/r/KjM0c3/1):

- `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\))*` - 0+ repetitions of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\([^()]*\)` - same as above, `(...)` substring.

The `.replace(/^\(|\)$/g, '')` part will remove the first `(` and last `)`, and `.split(/\)\s*\(/)` will split with `)(` having any amount of whitespaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.prototype.match()` with lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```js
const extract = (string) => string.match(/(?<=\().+?(?=\))/g);

console.log(extract('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)'));
console.log(extract('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc) '));
console.log(extract('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc) (cde)'));
console.log(extract('Sdfg dfg ldfgh (abc)(cde) (efgh)'));
```