# How can I extract an array with regex and without delimiters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

This is my input:

```
$.drawPlots({"times":[1578009600,1578096000,1578182400,1578268800,1578355200,1578441600,1578528000,1578614400,1578700800,1578787200,1578873600,1578960000,1579046400,1579132800,1579219200,1579305600,1579392000,1579478400,1579564800,1579651200,1579737600],"plots":{"assigned":[9,0,0,24,17,21,17,23,0,0,28,20,32,19,12,0,0,15,25,36,19],"closed":[15,0,0,34,46,37,38,70,0,0,42,21,67,48,54,0,0,41,38,55,19],"created":[21,2,2,38,28,33,39,62,2,1,43,27,36,53,33,1,1,44,41,58,20],"deleted":[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"edited":[3,0,0,43,207,2,4,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,2,3,0],"overdue":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],"reopened":[0,0,0,4,6,4,2,3,0,0,3,5,4,3,4,0,0,5,2,2,5]},"events":["assigned","closed","created","deleted","edited","overdue","reopened"]});
    // Set Selected Period For Dashboard Stats and Export
```

And I want to return

```
{"times":[1578009600,1578096000,1578182400,1578268800,1578355200,1578441600,1578528000,1578614400,1578700800,1578787200,1578873600,1578960000,1579046400,1579132800,1579219200,1579305600,1579392000,1579478400,1579564800,1579651200,1579737600],"plots":{"assigned":[9,0,0,24,17,21,17,23,0,0,28,20,32,19,12,0,0,15,25,36,19],"closed":[15,0,0,34,46,37,38,70,0,0,42,21,67,48,54,0,0,41,38,55,19],"created":[21,2,2,38,28,33,39,62,2,1,43,27,36,53,33,1,1,44,41,58,20],"deleted":[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"edited":[3,0,0,43,207,2,4,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,2,3,0],"overdue":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],"reopened":[0,0,0,4,6,4,2,3,0,0,3,5,4,3,4,0,0,5,2,2,5]},"events":["assigned","closed","created","deleted","edited","overdue","reopened"]}
```

One of my attempts ended up like this:

```
d,r,a,w,P,l,o,t,s,(,{,t,i,m,e,s,[,1,5,7,8,0,0,9,6,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,0,9,6,0,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,1,8,2,4,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,2,6,8,8,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,3,5,5,2,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,4,4,1,6,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,5,2,8,0,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,6,1,4,4,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,7,0,0,8,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,7,8,7,2,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,8,7,3,6,0,0,,,1,5,7,8,9,6,0,0,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,0,4,6,4,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,1,3,2,8,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,2,1,9,2,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,3,0,5,6,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,3,9,2,0,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,4,7,8,4,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,5,6,4,8,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,6,5,1,2,0,0,,,1,5,7,9,7,3,7,6,0,0,],,,p,l,o,t,s,{,a,s,s,i,g,n,e,d,[,9,,,0,,,0,,,2,4,,,1,7,,,2,1,,,1,7,,,2,3,,,0,,,0,,,2,8,,,2,0,,,3,2,,,1,9,,,1,2,,,0,,,0,,,1,5,,,2,5,,,3,6,,,1,9,],,,c,l,o,s,e,d,[,1,5,,,0,,,0,,,3,4,,,4,6,,,3,7,,,3,8,,,7,0,,,0,,,0,,,4,2,,,2,1,,,6,7,,,4,8,,,5,4,,,0,,,0,,,4,1,,,3,8,,,5,5,,,1,9,],,,c,r,e,a,t,e,d,[,2,1,,,2,,,2,,,3,8,,,2,8,,,3,3,,,3,9,,,6,2,,,2,,,1,,,4,3,,,2,7,,,3,6,,,5,3,,,3,3,,,1,,,1,,,4,4,,,4,1,,,5,8,,,2,0,],,,d,e,l,e,t,e,d,[,4,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,],,,e,d,i,t,e,d,[,3,,,0,,,0,,,4,3,,,2,0,7,,,2,,,4,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,2,,,1,,,1,,,2,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,2,,,3,,,0,],,,o,v,e,r,d,u,e,[,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,1,,,1,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,1,,,0,,,0,,,0,],,,r,e,o,p,e,n,e,d,[,0,,,0,,,0,,,4,,,6,,,4,,,2,,,3,,,0,,,0,,,3,,,5,,,4,,,3,,,4,,,0,,,0,,,5,,,2,,,2,,,5,],},,,e,v,e,n,t,s,[,a,s,s,i,g,n,e,d,,,c,l,o,s,e,d,,,c,r,e,a,t,e,d,,,d,e,l,e,t,e,d,,,e,d,i,t,e,d,,,o,v,e,r,d,u,e,,,r,e,o,p,e,n,e,d,],},),;,/,/,S,e,t,S,e,l,e,c,t,e,d,P,e,r,i,o,d,F,o,r,D,a,s,h,b,o,a,r,d,S,t,a,t,s,a,n,d,E,x,p,o,r,t
```

For the above I used:

```
const regex = /[^\\\:\$\s\.\"]/gm;
const plot = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[8].firstChild.data
const array = plot.match(regex)
```

I think it's the match() method thats inserting the delimiters, so how can I prevent that? And also, how can I write the regex to only include the characters included in the curly brackets?

Comment: What is the difference between your input and the expected output ?

Comment: So you basically just want to “remove the function call” around this? Strip `$.drawPlots(` from the beginning, and `);` from the end? Always for that specific method, or does it need to be dynamic in some way?

Comment: I think this is what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript

Comment: @04FS yeah exactly that. Just once. Is there a way to match only the argument? And Cid, the returned array does not preserve the hierarchy of the input I beleive.