# How to extract value using regex javascript in a generic form

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these values:

```
skew(1deg)
rotate(3)
skewY(10deg)
matrix(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

matrix could also be:

```
matrix(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

All i want to do is using regex generically extracting the exact values from above.

What i tried:

```
/skew\([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*\)/g
/rotate\([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*\)/g
/skewY\([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*\)/g
/matrix\([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*\)/g
```

so using the css properties like skew, rotate, skewY and matrix, i need to pass in these properties but want the value from the css property till the end character ")" generically, how can this be achieved.

Comment: Why regex? is there a pattern you need only a specific match?

Comment: the css value specifically needs to be passed, but from the end of the css value being passed i need to get the values from the end of the css value to the end character which is ")". it is looking for a specific match as skew, rotate and other properties are being passed. But generically i need to get the value also from "(" and ")" generically, or has this regex need to be done specifically on every css property or value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of an alternation to match one of the options. If you want the value between the parenthesis you could use a capturing group.

```
\b(?:skewY?|rotate|matrix)\(([^()]+)\)
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `skewY?|rotate|matrix` Match either skew, skewY, rotate or matrix
- `)` Close group
- `\( Match`(
  - `([^()]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char other than `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZUEZf8/1)

If your intent is to use only the allowed characters from the patterns that you tried, you could use:

```
\b(?:skewY?|rotate|matrix)\([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*(?:, ?[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JfNkYl/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(?:skewY?|rotate|matrix)\(([^()]+)\)/;
["skew(1deg)",
  "rotate(3)",
  "skewY(10deg)",
  "matrix(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)"
]
.forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such a generic pattern:

```
skew(.|\n)*?\) | rotate(.|\n)*?\) | matrix(.|\n)*?\)
```

Add each match to an array and when you finish remove the unnecessary strings at the end and at the beginning (i.e skew(...rotate(...) using a simple `Replace()` function.

[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/regextester?query=6b03760d-5b88-4e94-ac02-f594d1050dcd)

According to comment for this answer, **Javascript Flavor** for the regex pattern:

```
skew([^])*?(\))|rotate([^])*?(\))|matrix([^])*?(\))
```

Comment: Please, DON'T use `(.|\n)`, use `[^]` in javascript.

Comment: @Toto Thank you for your comment! a javascript flavor pattern was added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found this on stack overflow:

[Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

And works:

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
```

So gets the value between the brackets also.