# Extract all chars between parenthesis

Tags: regex

I used

```
let regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
```

to extract

```
(test(()))
```

from

```
aaaaa (test(())) bbbb
```

but I get only this

```
(test(()
```

How can I fix my regex ?

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47864833/3832970

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a negative character set, since parentheses (both `(` and `)`) may appear inside the match you want. Greedily repeat instead, so that you match as much as possible, until the engine backtracks and finds the first `)` from the right:

```js
console.log(
  'aaaaa (test(())) bbbb'
    .match(/\(.*\)/)[0]
);
```

Keep in mind that this (and JS regex solutions in general) cannot guarantee balanced parentheses, at least not without additional post-processing/validation.