# Regex get string between ()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the text

```
   var text =  (hello) world this is (hi) text
```

I want to write a regex function so I can get

```
parseText(text) // returns ['hello', 'hi']
```

I tried this but not work:

```
'(hello) world this is (hi) text'.match('((.*?))')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried this but not work: '(hello) world this is (hi) text'.match('\((.*?)\)')

Comment: @coinhndp Please edit your question and put that information in it

Comment: `match` only returns the first match if you don't use the `g` flag for the regular expression: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match . Also you are passing a string literal, not a regular expression which makes things trickier. You can learn about regular expressions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Which makes it trickier? Could you explain it for me

Comment: brackets are a meta-character (in most regex flavours at least), you need to escape them when you want to match the actual characters. I'd use `\(([^)]*)\)`, but `\((.*?)\)` is fine too

Comment: If you use a string literal instead of an regular expression literal you have to "double escape" meta characters because the backslash is also the escape character in string literals. It's not difficult, but it trips people up who don't understand how escape sequences work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with:
`/\([^\)]+\)/g`

1. `\(`: escaped char
2. `[^\)]+`: one or more character<sup>(*including symbols*)</sup> until `)` char.
3. `\)`: escaped char
4. `g` flag: search all coincidences

[image]

```js
const regex = /\([^\)]+\)/g;
const str = `(hello) world this is (hi) text`;

console.log(
  str.match(regex) // this returns an string array
    .map(i => i.slice(1, -1)) // remove first and last char
);
```

**TIPS:**

> About point #2, you can change to `[\)]*` to take effect over zero
> or more character.

> If you need only string, you can use `\w+` or `\w*`.

> If you need only words you can use `/\(\b\w+\b\)/g`

Comment: I suggest replacing `i.substr(1, i.length-2)` with `i.slice(1,-1)`

Comment: @JanStránský yeah!

Answer (score 1):

```
'(hello) world this is (hi) text'.match(/\([\w]*\)/g)
```

This returns `[ "(hello)", "(hi)" ]` and you can run another parse function to remove that extra parenthesis.

```js
const text = '(hello) world this is (hi) text';
const list = text.match(/\([\w]*\)/g);
const parsed = list.map(item => item.replace(/\(|\)/g, ''));
console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: `list.map(item => item.slice(1,-1));` is maybe more readable?

Answer (score 1):

You can find several options [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript).

Apart from using groups or postprocessing of the `match` results, you can use single regex `match` using lookahead / lookbehind:

```js
var text = " (hello) world this is (hi) text"
var output = text.match(/(?<=\().*?(?=\))/g)
console.log(output)
```

output:

```
[ 'hello', 'hi' ]
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=...)` ... positive lookbehind. The match is preceded be `...`, but the `...` is not included in the match
- `(?<=\()` ... positive lookbehind for `(` character
- `.*` ... zero or more times of any character
- `.*?` ... nongreedy version of `.*`
- `(?=...)` ... positive lookahead, the match is followed by `...` but the `...` is not included in the match
- `(?=\))` ... positive lookahead for `)` character
- `/.../g` ... `g` is global flag, match finds all, not only the first, occurrence
- do not forget to escape "special characters", e.g. parentheses