# Getting the content between two characters

Tags: javascript, replace

So I have this (example) string: `1234VAR239582358X`

And I want to get what's in between VAR and X. I can easily replace it using `.replace(/VAR.*X/, "replacement");`
But, how would I get the `/VAR.*X/`as a variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

Comment: More specifically, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17779833/407650

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for might be

```
string.match(/VAR(.*)X/)[1]
```

The brackets around the .* mark a group. Those groups are returned inside the Array that `match` creates :)

If you want to only replace what's in between "VAR" and "X" it would be

```
string.replace(/VAR(.*)X/, "VAR" + "replacement" + "X");
```

Or more generic:

```
string.replace(/(VAR).*(X)/, "$1replacement$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the RegExp class, new RegExp(`${VAR}.*X`)

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as variable like this,

```
const pattern = "VAR.*X";
const reg = new RegExp(pattern);
```

Then use,

```
.replace(reg, "replacement");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you

> want to get what's in between VAR and X

then using `.*` would do the job for the given example string.

But note that is will match until the end of the string, and then backtrack to the first occurrence of `X` it can match, being the last occurrence of the X char in the string and possible match too much.

If you want to match only the digits, you can match 1+ digits in a capture group using `VAR(\d+)X`

```js
const regex = /VAR(\d+)X/;
const str = "1234VAR239582358X";
const m = str.match(regex);

if (m) {
  let myVariable = m[1];
  console.log(myVariable);
}
```

Or you can match until the first occurrence of an `X` char using a negated character class `VAR([^\r\nX]+)X`

```js
const regex = /VAR([^\r\nX]+)X/;
const str = "1234VAR239582358X";
const m = str.match(regex);

if (m) {
  let myVariable = m[1];
  console.log(myVariable);
}
```