# How to get the filtered data with two or more return values with function includes

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var arr1 = [
  "T-1",
  "CAT"
]

var arr2 = [
  "Lemuel F (T-1)",
  "Levi C (T-1)",
  "Monfel (T-2)",
  "JC (T-1)",
  "Wrecker (CAT)"
]

const arr3 = arr2.filter(a => {
  return (a.includes(arr1[0]));
});
console.log("arr3", arr3);
```

This is the output I get :

```
[ 'Lemuel F (T-1)', 'Levi C (T-1)', 'JC (T-1)' ]
```

This is the output I'm trying to get

```
[ 'Lemuel F (T-1)', 'Levi C (T-1)', 'JC (T-1)','Wrecker (CAT)' ]
```

I'm trying to use multiple includes but I still cant find a way. I've tried this syntax

```
 return (a.includes(arr1[0]) && (a.includes(arr1[1]
```

Comment: `arr3 = arr2.filter(v1 => arr1.some(v2 => v1.includes(v2)))`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen why post that as acomment? This question is more than of a high enough quality to be answered

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question here is how to use include in your situation, however I also recommend using regex, since it simplifies the issue quite a bit and only requires you to iterate over each element once.

```js
const arr1 = ["T-1", "CAT"];

const arr2 = [
  "Lemuel F (T-1)",
  "Levi C (T-1)",
  "Monfel (T-2)",
  "JC (T-1)",
  "Wrecker (CAT)"
];

// using includes
const arr3 = arr2.filter((value2) => arr1.some((value1) => value2.includes(value1)));
console.log(arr3);

// using regex
const regex = new RegExp(arr1.join("|"), "g");
const arr4 = arr2.filter((value) => value.match(regex));
console.log(arr4);
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution that can be used for your case is to have a Regular Expression that tests for the existence of the substrings inside the sentences array.

```js
const subStrings = ["T-1", "CAT"],
  strings = ["Lemuel F (T-1)", "Levi C (T-1)", "Monfel (T-2)", "JC (T-1)", "Wrecker (CAT)"],
  /** 
   * create a RegExp object on the fly
   * the "|" token acts like the logical OR operator
   * basically we'll have this regex: "T-1|CAT"
   */
  regExp = new RegExp(subStrings.join('|')),
  res = strings.filter(s => regExp.test(s));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking at an array intersection (`arr1` × `arr2`), but with some slightly tweaked logic as you want the predicate to look at the string inside the parenthesis in `arr2`. You can use [regex to extract the keyword you want to match (that is encapsulated between parenthesis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript), and check if it exists in `arr1`:

```
arr2.filter(entry => {
  const keyword = entry.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
  return arr1.includes(keyword);
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example based on your code, which returns the data as you expect:

```js
const arr1 = ["T-1", "CAT"];

const arr2 = [
  "Lemuel F (T-1)",
  "Levi C (T-1)",
  "Monfel (T-2)",
  "JC (T-1)",
  "Wrecker (CAT)",
];

const arr3 = arr2.filter(entry => arr1.includes(entry.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]));
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr3 = arr2.filter(item=>arr1.some(item2=>item2.includes(item)))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.