# How to get all possible overlapping matches for a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on the MIU system problem from "Gödel, Escher, Bach" chapter 2.

One of the rules states

`Rule III: If III occurs in one of the strings in your collection, you may make a new string with U in place of III.`

Which means that the string `MIII` can become `MU`, but for other, longer strings there may be multiple possibilities [matches in brackets]:

- `MIIII` could yield

  - `M[III]I` >> `MUI`
  - `MI[III]` >> `MIU`
- `MUIIIUIIIU` could yield

  - `MU[III]UIIIU` >> `MUUUIIIU`
  - `MUIIIU[III]U` >> `MUIIIUUU`
- `MUIIIIU` could yield

  - `MU[III]IU` >> `MUUIU`
  - `MUI[III]U` >> `MUIUU`

Clearly regular expressions such as `/(.*)III(.*)/` are helpful, but I can't seem to get them to generate every possible match, just the first one it happens to find.

Is there a way to generate every possible match?

(Note, I can think of ways to do this entirely manually, but I am hoping there is a better way using the built in tools, regex or otherwise)

(Edited to clarify overlapping needs.)

Comment: Are you asking how to get _all_ the occurrences of III anywhere in a string, including overlapping matches, and having them returned in an array?

Comment: Yes, as per the examples. e.g. MIIII should have two matches, for M[III]I and MI[III]. (These go on to become MUI and MIU). Exec looked promising, but it won't handle overlapping cases.

Comment: `RegExp.exec` _can_ work for you, but you'd need to play with match objects, as in Kolink's answer.  In this case, `indexOf` is probably better, but regexes are certainly more general.

Comment: Hofstadter spent some time in Oregon too, didn't he?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the regex you need: `/III/g` - simple enough, right? Now here's how you use it:

```
var text = "MUIIIUIIIU", find = "III", replace "U",
    regex = new RegExp(find,"g"), matches = [], match;
while(match = regex.exec(text)) {
    matches.push(match);
    regex.lastIndex = match.index+1;
}
```

That `regex.lastIndex...` line overrides the usual regex behaviour of not matching results that overap. Also I'm using a `RegExp` constructor to make this more flexible. You could even build it into a function this way.

Now you have an array of match objects, you can do this:

```
matches.forEach(function(m) { // older browsers need a shim or old-fashioned for loop
    console.log(text.substr(0,m.index)+replace+text.substr(m.index+find.length));
});
```

**EDIT:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2sbLc/) is a JSFiddle demonstrating the above code.

Comment: Hrm, why +1, not -1? This doesn't appear to solve my problem, I'm still poking at it. I'll report back with what I find.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd think `-1` would work. You need to move *forward* in the string, not backward. Moving backward would repeatedly find the exact same match and give you an infinite loop. Edited a JSFiddle link into the answer.

Comment: Missread the above, I was editing the last index directly, which turns out to be much less useful. This appears to work, thanks much!

Comment: Nice, did some googling on how to do regexp searches in JavaScript accounting for overlapping matches. Probably looked for 30min until I found this post with the simple `regex.lastIndex = match.index + 1` solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes regexes are overkill.  In your case a simple `indexOf` might be fine too!

Here is, admittedly, a hack, but you can transform it into pretty, reusable code on your own:

```
var s = "MIIIIIUIUIIIUUIIUIIIIIU";
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; true; i += 1) {
    i = s.indexOf("III", i);
    if (i === -1) {
        break;
    }
    results.push(i);
}
console.log("Match positions: " + JSON.stringify(results));
```

It takes care of overlaps just fine, and at least to me, the `indexOf` just looks simpler.

Comment: Yes, this case is fairly simple. They get a bit more complex, and ideally it would be essentially open ended.

Comment: Agreed.  You will want something more powerful for the Mx → Mxx rule :)

Comment: Yes, fortunately the regexes handle the Mx -> Mxx case nicely: `newTheorems.push(
      startingTheorem.replace(
        /(M)(.+)/i,
        "$1$2$2"
      )
    );`

Comment: Aaaaccctually, it's even easier than that: `function Rule2(s) {return s + s.substring(1);}` because in the MIU-puzzle, _all_ strings start with `M`!

Comment: True, nice use of built in tools. This is helping me learn javascript regular expressions though. I already know C ;)