# JS RegEx to match all characters (including newline) between two strings but without the two strings?

Tags: javascript, regex, newline, delimiter

### Example Text:

```
<div id="not-wanted">
no no 
no 
</div>
<div id="wanted">I want 
only this 
text
</div> no no no
no no
<div id="not-wanted">
no no no 
</div>
<div id="wanted">no no
no no</div>
<div id="wanted">
no no     
</div>
```

### Should deliver:

```
I want 
only this 
text
```

### Or better:

```
I want only this text
```

### Unfortunately, my solution catches the 2 delimitation strings also:

```
$('#put').append(/<div id="wanted">[^<>]*<\/div>/.exec(strg)[0]);
```

==>

```
<div id="wanted">I want 
only this 
text
</div>
```

### Online example

http://regex101.com/r/rF7jR9

### Question

What regular expression for Java Script can deliver the characters between delimiting strings, if there are also `\n` and `\r` resend. It would be nice, if `\n` and `\r` are removed from the delivered string. The RegExpr should work fast.

Comment: Why using regex?  In this example, you have object "div" with known ID.  you can use getElementById('wanted').innerHTML to get the content.

Comment: If the example text is in `strg`. How to use it? `var txt = strg.getElementById('wanted').innerHTML` is not working.

Answer (score 11):

Now I know how to:

```
$('#put').append(/<div id="wanted">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/.exec(strg)[1]);
```

Thank you Jerry for the `(`group`)` hint. `[\s\S]` stands for every character. `*?` stop after first found `<\/div>`.

Comment: excellent, thank you - very useful for finding blocks of comments that all start with a specific string when refactoring, since in my case I certainly did not want to remove all comments everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group and ignore the full match?

```
$('#put').append(/<div id="wanted">([^<>]*)<\/div>/.exec(strg)[1]);
                                   ^------^                    ^
```

`( ... )` is a capture group and since it's the first one in the regex, it gets to the first capture group, hence the `1` near the end.