# Regex extract list of strings between two strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string out of which I want to extract a list of strings that are contained between two strings: `['` and `']` . I tried several regex rules ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript) in particular) that I found online but the problem is in escaping the characters correctly to make the regex work.

How can I extract a list of strings between two strings? I want to do something like this:

```
List<string> TheListOfStrings = Regex.Matches(TheText, "....");
```

The source is a JavaScript block from which I want to extract object keys: for instrance,`TheObject['SomeProp'] = TheOtherObject['OtherProp']` and so the list should contain `SomeProp` and `OtherProp`; the keys can be present multiple times in the input text.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: So, the source looks like ['a, b, c'] or ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] or what exactly? Could you show us?

Comment: Further, could one string contain multiple matches, such as `"a['bc']d['ef']gh']"`?

Comment: @ClickRick: yes that can happen; again, all that matters is the content between [' and '] so in your case, it should return bc and ef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your <s>only</s> main difficulty is in making the square brackets be recognised as delimiting text rather than as part of the regex.

```
string input = "a['bc']d['ef']gh']";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\['(?<key>.*?)'\]");
var listOfKeys = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["key"].Value);
```

does the trick.

If performance is important and it's going to be run multiple times, then compiling the regex will see a noticeable win:

```
string input = "a['bc']d['ef']gh']";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\['(?<key>.*?)'\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(input);
var listOfKeys = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["key"].Value);
```

Comment: Try now I've debugged it *properly*.

Comment: So the good news is that it works. The problem is that the previous implementation I had (manually looping through the input string) returned 3331 items and the regex you have is returing 3330 items. I need to see why but overall, the regex took less than a second vs my manual implementation which currently takes over 10s.

Comment: Would you particularly want it to perform faster over large input data?

Comment: Ok, everything works. The faster the better, of course; this is part of a background task where users are not involved so perf is not essential but anything helps! What do you suggest?

Comment: I've added a "compiled regex" variant. Time the old and the new over your data.

Comment: Ok, so the code went from about 30ms to about 20ms so it did improve with the compiled option on. Note that the previous code took about 12-15 seconds to run... Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use the general pattern

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

It uses lookbehind and lookahead which looks for patterns without including them in the result.

Where
  *prefix*   is `\['`; the left bracket is escaped.
  *find*      is `.*?`; sequence of any chars but as few as possible.
  *suffix*   is `']`

```
(?<=\[').*?(?='])
```

```cs
List<string> TheListOfStrings = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\[').*?(?='])")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

---

If you are calling the same regular expression repeatedly, create an resuable instance of it instead of calling the static method. Also if you are using it many times, consider using the `Compiled` option. It will run faster; however, the tradeoff is that the initialization time is longer.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[').*?(?='])", RegexOptions.Compiled);

while (loop_condition) {

    List<string> TheListOfStrings = regex.Matches(input)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
    ...

}
```

Comment: Show that pattern in context, extracting the desired parts of the input string and producing the desired output strings, using the test data in the comments under the question.

Comment: I added a code example. The example is tested and produces the desired output.

Comment: I tried that: it works and the code is cleaner. Then, I put a stopwatch and timed both. This code runs in 217ms vs 10ms for the other code. I thought it had to do with the compilation of the regex so on the following call, the results were 213ms vs 9ms. Not sure why such a difference but that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: I added an exmaple that will be faster if you are calling it many times.

Answer (score 1):

This may meet your needs: `(?<=\[")[^"]+(?="\])|(?<=\[')[^']+(?='\])`

for `a['bc']d['ef']gh']` this returns `bc` and `ef`

Comment: I tried this: var Test = Regex.Matches(TheText, "(?<=\[")[^"]+(?="\])|(?<=\[')[^']+(?='\])"); using your regex but there's a problem in the rule that's preventing compilation; it's underlined red.

Comment: try this: string pattern = "(?<=\\[\")[^\"]+(?=\"\\])|(?<=\\[')[^']+(?='\\])";

Comment: still has "unrecognized escape sequences" underlines.

Comment: @frenchie It might be as simple as the missing `@` sign before the string.