# How does this regexp work?

Tags: javascript, regex

`RegExes` give me headaches. I have a very simple `regex` but I don't understand how it works.

The code:

```
var str= "startBlablablablablaend";
var regex = /start(.*?)end/;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log( match[0] ); //startBlablablablablaend
console.log( match[1] ); //Blablablablabla
```

What I ultimately want would be the second one, in other words the text between the two delimiters (start,end).

My questions:

- How does it work? (each character explained please)
- Why does it match two different things?
- Is there a better way to get match[1]?
- If I want to get all the text's between all the start-end instances, how would I go about it?

For the **last question**, what I mean:

```
var str = "startBla1end startBla2end startBla3end";
var regex = /start(.*?)end/gmi;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log( match ); // [ "startBla1end" , "startBla2end" , "startBla3end" ]
```

What I need is:

```
console.log( match ); // [ "Bla1" , "Bla2" , "Bla3" ];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Mozilla has a great [reference and tutorial for regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in JavaScript.

Comment: I'll check it out then, thank you! In the meantime anyone can save me some time explaining this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How does it work?**

- `start` matches `start` in the string
- `(.*?)` non greedy match for character
- `end` matches the end in the string

Matching

```
startBlablablablablaend
  |
start

startBlablablablablaend
     |
     .

startBlablablablablaend
      |
      .

# and so on since quantifier * matches any number of character. ? makes the match non greedy

startBlablablablablaend
                     |
                    end
```

**Why does it match two different things?**

It doesnt match 2 differnt things

- `match[0]` will contain the entire match
- `match[1]` will contain the first capture group (the part matched in the first paranthesis)

**Is there a better way to get match[1]?**

Short answer No

If you are using languages other than javascript. its possible using look arounds

```
(?<=start)(.*?)(?=end)
#Blablablablabla
```

**Note** This wont work with javascript as it doesnt support negative lookbehinds

**Last Question**

The best that you can get from a single match statement would be

```
var str = "startBla1end startBla2end startBla3end";
var regex = /start(.*?)(?=end)/gmi;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log( match ); // [ "startBla" , "startBla2" , "startBla3" ]
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves everything but the last question hahaha! Anyway you have the most complete answer, so green tick it is!

Comment: @Rou You are welcome :) To solve your last question the best result you can hope is using a look ahead. which will not contain `end` in the output. start can be replaced by normal iteration throught the array thereafter

Answer (score 1):

You need not to do a much effort on it.

Try this this regex:

```
start(.*)end
```

You can look at this stackoverflow question which already been answered before.

[Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out too! Somehow i missed that one (I've checked a lot of "get string in between with regexp" questions)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your **last question**, you can split up your string and iterate:

```
var str = "startBla1end startBla2end startBla3end";
var str_array = str.split(" ");
```

Then iterate over each element of the str_array using your existing code to extract each Bla# substring.

Comment: Thanks this would be my second choice, I guess I'll do that! :)

Comment: Yeah there's probably a more elegant way, if by elegant I mean an even more complex regex. But since we all hate reading other peoples complex regex, I say keep it simple even if it's a few more lines of code.