# JavaScript RegEx match unless wrapped with [nocode][/nocode] tags

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

My current code is:

```
var user_pattern = this.settings.tag;
user_pattern = user_pattern.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"); // escape regex
var pattern = new RegExp(user_pattern.replace(/%USERNAME%/i, "(\\S+)"), "ig");
```

Where `this.settings.tag` is a string such as "[user=%USERNAME%]" or "@%USERNAME%". The code uses `pattern.exec(str)` to find any username in the corresponding tag and works perfectly fine. For example, if `str = "Hello, [user=test]"` then `pattern.exec(str)` will find `test`.

This works fine, but I want to be able to stop it from matching if the string is wrapped in `[nocode][/nocode]` tags. For example, if `str = "[nocode]Hello, [user=test], how are you?[/nocode]" then`pattern.exec(str)` should not match anything.

I'm not quite sure where to start. I tried using a `(?![nocode])` before and after the pattern, but to no avail. Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm not a regexp expert but what if you check for [nocode] separately, maybe with indexOf('[nocode]']>=0 or another regexp pattern? Or does it have to be one pattern?

Comment: A single string could consist of multiple `[user=]` tags with some wrapped in `[nocode]`s unfortunately.

Comment: looks like that won't be a problem with my solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe filter out `[nocode]` before trying to find the username(s)?

```
pattern.exec(str.replace(/\[nocode\](.*)\[\/nocode\]/g,''));
```

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for because now you have to use two separate regular expressions, however code readability is important too and doing it this way is definitely better in that aspect. Hope this helps

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1f485Lda/1/

It's based on this: [Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: This definitely seems to be a step forward. There's only one thing I can see that might stop this method from working, but I'll attempt to get around it first and if it doesn't work I'll let you know. I'll hold of on best answer until then.

Answer (score 0):

I would just test if the string starts with [nocode] first:

```
/^\[nocode\]/.test('[nocode]');
```

Then simply do not process it.

Comment: A single string could consist of multiple `[user=]` tags with some wrapped in `[nocode]`s unfortunately.

Comment: I would suggest creating a routine that would normalize your data into something predictable then proceed with parsing.  You may want to use string indexes to extract sections of the string into multiple strings etc.  If you provide a few more examples such as the one you are mentioning in your questions it would be easier for the community to help with solutions.