# Regex for picking a Value After “@word_”

Tags: regex

I need a Regex that can actually get any letter that is inserted after "@ and _"

```
http://api.psusedo.com/board@top_test
```

I found it until @top_test.

```
\@(.*)
```

What I get in return is "test".

Comment: What is consistent about the string? What language are you using this in? Maybe `@([a-z]+_?)+`

Comment: "I need a Regex that can actually get any letter that is inserted after "@ and _"" --- this is not formal enough. And tbh it's not clear what you want to extract. Once you have the clear and non-vague requirement it would be much easier to write a regular expression.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5642329/3832970) or [my answer with some more explanation and variations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970) in the linked thread.