# Regex to extract Multiline inbetween << and >>

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use Javascript regular expression which captures multi line text between specific string. I used <<\n((.+\n)+)>> but is not capturing the information which I was looking for.
**Example:**

```
Event Name: UPDATE 
Log Type: INTERNAL UPDATE 
ticket: denied

Please comment between << >>
<<
Cannot approve your request.
Please provide more information and re raise a request.
Also attache the approval form with it.
>>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970

Comment: I have updated the code in https://regex101.com/r/CLyqIB/1

Comment: ([\s\S]*?)<<([\s\S]*?)>> this one works guys.