# How to find strings between two and more another strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regexp:

```
let re = /\[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] (.*)/gm;
let regex = new RegExp(re);
```

And my string:

```
[Max] [2017-12-12 15:59 (UTC +02:00)] [Technical issues] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
[Corben Dallas] [2017-12-20 12:48 (UTC +02:00)] [Technical issues] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
[Max] [2017-12-12 15:59 (UTC +02:00)] [Technical issues] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

I need to retrive text of each person. But I my problem is that text could contain newlines `\n` and my regexp retrives text only to the end of the line.
Please look at the example here https://regex101.com/r/t7zV1U/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: _my problem is that text could contain newlines \n and my regexp retrives text only to the end of the line._ Just set multiline flag (`m`)

Comment: @hindmost, I use flags gm, I edited post.

Comment: [`\[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] ([^\[]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/t7zV1U/2) ?

Comment: @Gurman, cool it's work. thank you

Comment: @Dmitro Gurman's answer is fantastic but it will fail if `[` is found in any sentences. You need to use a tempered greedy token to ensure it stops matching when it finds `[` at the start of the string (as I've done in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/jkVcay/2): Switch to PCRE flavour to see actual matches live in string.

```
\[([^\]]*)\] \[([^\]]*)\] \[([^\]]*)\] ((?:(?!^\[)[\s\S])*)
```

#### Usage

```js
var s = `[Max] [2017-12-12 15:59 (UTC +02:00)] [Technical issues] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
[Corben Dallas] [2017-12-20 12:48 (UTC +02:00)] [Technical issues] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
[Max] [2017-12-12 15:59 (UTC +02:00)] [Technical issues] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. `

var r = /\[([^\]]*)\] \[([^\]]*)\] \[([^\]]*)\] ((?:(?!^\[)[\s\S])*)/gm
let m;

while ((m = r.exec(s)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === r.lastIndex) {
        r.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

### Explanation

First to note is that I changed all of your `\[(.*?)\]` to `\[([^\]]*)\]`. This is because `\[([^\]]*)\]` actually performs better than the lazy quantifier in this case (`[^\]]*` means match anything that is not `]`).

- `((?:(?!^\[)[\s\S])*)` Capture the following into capture group 4

  - `(?:(?!^\[)[\s\S])*` Match the following any number of times (this is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat))

    - `(?!^\[)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

      - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
      - `\[` Match the left square bracket `[` literally
    - `[\s\S]` Match any character (includes newline characters)

Comment: Thank you.Your answer is awesome

Answer (score 0):

It should be the **Group 1** of this RegExp: `\[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\]/gm`

See: https://regex101.com/r/tC6mDp/1

You just need to match the brackets:

- Group 1 will be the name
- Group 2 the date
- Group 3 the topic?