# Regex to get string between two specific tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

```
[device]Some device[/device]
```

I am trying to write regex that will return only **"Some device"**.

```
/[device](.*?)[/device]/i.exec(str) // doesn't work
/[device](.*)[\/device]/g.exec(text) // doesn't work
```

I am not sure how to extract it?

I already tried solution from [Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript) and it doesn't work for string like `[][/]`

```
[device]Some device[/device]
```

return

```
evice]Some device[/device] and all other strings.
```

Comment: 1) `[` is a special char outside a character class and must be escaped, and `/` must be escaped since it is used as a regex delimiter. 2) matching a substring between two strings is a long solved issue. 3) "doesn't work" is not helpful for people who cannot test your solution - what doesn't work? Closed as a dupe with 2 close reasons that help you solve the issue.

Comment: *I already tried solution from [Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970) and it doesn't work for string like `[][/]`*  - you just need to learn which chars should be escaped in a regex to match literal chars. See the second close reason. BTW, you seem to have read the accepted answer that is not helpful much. You need to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970).

Comment: Yes I am reading but still don't understand how to escape [str][/str]

Comment: You only need to escape `[` and `/`, and see the *Sample regex usage in JavaScript* code snippet to see how to get multiple matches.

Comment: `/[title/](.*)[/title/]/.exec` will not work

Comment: Look, `\[title\](.*)\[/title\]` can't match `[device]Some device[/device]` - it is obvious. You do not escape `/` thus your pattern is invalid. Why escape `]`? It is not special outside of character class. See https://jsfiddle.net/qbbkj6ez/.

Comment: `\[device\](.*)\[\/device\]`