# JS match string with regex but return part of string

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible using regex in JavaScript to match a string but only return part of the match?

For example in the string match `collections/electronics/products` but only return `electronics`

`https://website.com/collections/electronics/products/some-product`

This is what I have so far:

`/(\/collections\/)(.*?)(\/products\/)/ig`

Comment: Explanations for all kinds of scenarios and example code to fetch one or multiple results is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970).

Comment: I had to amend the JavaScript to return the second group:

`var re = /(.*)\/collections\/(.*?)\/products\/(.*)/ig;
var collection = location.href.replace(re, "$2");`