# How to get all matches between 2 strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string:

```
"My cow gives milk, my cow always gives milk".
```

I want to extract the text between `"cow"` and `"milk"`, which will give me

```
["gives", "always gives"].
```

I've tried `string.match('cow (.*?) milk')`, but it gives me

```
["cow gives milk", "gives"].
```

Comment: Your answer(s) are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970). You have no overlapping matches here, only several non-overlapping ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**matchAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and then take the groups only

```js
let str = "My cow gives milk, my cow always gives milk"
let op = str.matchAll(/cow (.*?) milk/g)

let final = [...op].map( value => value[1] )

console.log(final)
```

Alternative

```js
const regexp = RegExp('cow (.*?) milk','g');
const str = "My cow gives milk, my cow always gives milk"

while ((matches = regexp.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Matched value :-  ${matches[1]}`);
}
```

Comment: does not have the best [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility) though

Comment: @Aprillion you can use `exec` in that case, see the update,