# REGEX - How can I return text between two strings

Tags: regex

Link [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7j7eWy/1)
I am using   (FD.*?)FD   however I am missing every second expression - see regex. Any ideas?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970), scroll to *Scenario 3*.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing "FD" in your regex matches the "FD" in the input that starts the next "item" in the input text, so the entire next "item" is skipped, until it finds another "FD".

In a case like this, instead of specify `.*` followed by the pattern that starts the next item, you typically want to specify anything *not including* a pattern of `FD`.

Comment: Any suggestion how to do this?