# How to split the string based on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a dynamic string like below:

```
"intro":"1.[Model=FS7200 NVMe Control, IOGroups=1, SystemMemory=1536 GiB, AdapterType=16 Gb FC 4 Port Adapter Pair, P1_Type=DRP, P1_ExtentSize=1024 MiB, P1_ThinProvisioning=0-49%, P1_Compression=0-49%, P1_Deduplication=0-49%, P1A1_IOGrp=1]\nAn explanation could not be generated for this combination\nThe following error occurred: Problem in restriction !(IOGroups.equals(\"1\")) || (!P1A1_IOGrp.equals(\"1\") && !P1A1_IOGrp.equals(\"2\") && !P1A1_IOGrp.equals(\"3\")) && P2A1_IOGrp.equals(\"NA\") && P2_Type.equals(\"NA\") && P2_ExtentSize.equals(\"NA\") && P2_ThinProvisioning.equals(\"NA\") && P2_Compression.equals(\"NA\") && P2_Deduplication.equals(\"NA\") && P2A1_DriveValues.equals(\"NA\") && P2A1_DriveTechnology.equals(\"NA\") && P2A1_DriveType.equals(\"NA\") && P2A1_ArrayType.equals(\"NA\") && P2A1_TargetGroup.equals(\"NA\") && P2A1_StripSize.equals(\"NA\")\nResulting expression is too large to handle. Please consider simplifying your restriction by breaking it into several simpler ones\n\n"
```

Here, I want to split it on following basis:

The text after `An explanation` should show in next line.

The text after `restriction`, and before `Resulting` should show in blue color, and in next line.

The text after `Resulting` should show in normal black color, and in next line.

I am able to do splitting based on second condition, but not completely.

```
{item.intro.search('restriction') > 0 &&
  <h5>
   {i+1}> {item.intro.split('restriction')[0]}restriction
   <span style={{color:"blue"}}>
   {item.intro.split('restriction')[1]}
   </span>
  </h5>}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please add a more appropriate title to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I get your use case, you can replace **str1**  with your starting word and **str2** with your ending word.

In **newtext** you will get the string between str1 and str2

```
var re = /(.*word1\s+)(.*)(\s+word2.*)/;
var newtext = item.intro.replace(re, "$2");
```

you can try the solution available in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/tkP74/)
and try to make changes as per your use case.

The solution is referenced from [Regular expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642517/13465175)

A detailed explanation is also available in this [capturing group with a lazy dot matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/13465175).