# regex returns 'Cannot read property '0' of null' in match()

Tags: node.js, regex

This is the string i'm working with
`8 August 1994 (age 25 years)` I've been trying to match the `25` using

`(?<=age ).*?(?= years)`,

but it returns
`Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

It matches fine on regex101.com
https://regex101.com/r/P5JYKx/2, so I don't understand the issue?

code

```
string.match(/(?<=age ).*?(?= years)/)
```

I'm using javascript regex.

Comment: Okay, just did that.

Comment: @Nick Node.js supports lookbehinds. srb633, are you using the latest Node.js version?

Comment: Okay interesting, didn't know. I'm evaluating a page using headless chrome. That's probably why.

Comment: Are you sure `string` is actually what you think it is?

Comment: The `string.match()` is contained inside an if statement which can only be accessed if the string is what I need it to be. So yes it's the correct variable.

Comment: Let's assume it's because i'm using headless chrome, what alternative expression could I use for this task?

Comment: Just use good old capturing groups, `string.match(/age\s+(.*?)\s+years/)[1]`

Comment: Haha alright sweet thank you. Feel free to write up a reply, seems that the issue has come down to headless chrome not supporting lookbehinds rather then the regex it self.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970).

Comment: Great thank you @WiktorStribiżew