# find string between an equal sign and t= regex javascript to get YouTube id

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to get the string between `v=` and `&t` so in the case below I would get `1oDaF770-ws`

```
// I want to get 1oDaF770-ws from the url below

const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oDaF770-ws&t=67s"
```

I have the following code

```
const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oDaF770-ws&t=67s"
url.match(/(?<=v=\s*).*?(?=\s*&t=)/gs);
```

As you can see I have followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not using a regex at all for this. It will no longer work if the order of query parameters happens to change.

You can just parse the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and get the required query parameter:

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oDaF770-ws&t=67s');
const v = url.searchParams.get('v');

console.log(v);
```

Comment: nice, I didn't know about that one! thanks