# Find all strings in between two strings in Go

Tags: regex, go

I am working on extracting mutliple matches between two strings.

In the example below, I am trying to regex out an `A B C` substring out of my string.

Here is my code:

```golang
package main
    
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)
    
func main() {
    str:= "Movies: A B C Food: 1 2 3"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`[Movies:][^Food:]*`)
    match := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
    fmt.Println(match)
}
```

I am clearly doing something wrong in my regex. I am trying to get the `A B C` string between `Movies:` and `Food:`.

What is the proper regex to get all strings between two strings?

Comment: You're matching one character in the first set, and zero or one characters *not* in the second set.  I would review basic regex syntax and you should solve this easily.

Comment: I did look at the docs, obviously it wasn't that helpful, which is why I am here.

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks but that is not in Go language

Comment: Your problem isn't how you are using Go, your code will work fine once you fix your regex.  For such a basic match it won't differ much between engines

Comment: You could use for example https://regex101.com/ and set the language at the left to Golang. Lookarounds are not supported, so you could use a capture group approach which is shown on that page.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you but all of the patterns only show us how to get all characters that are not a number, or all characters that do not contain a certain letter, but is there a damn pattern where it isolates a word and parses the text between that word and another word. Why is this so hard?

Comment: Consider this broad match using a capture group `\bMovies: (.+?) Food:` which is a bit like `cow (.*?) milk` using a group as on the other page. See https://regex101.com/r/erh9WZ/1 Also you  you might read about [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) and [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that you used in your pattern.

Comment: thank you but that returns movies and food still not only the characters in between.

Comment: It is easy - https://play.golang.org/p/8DhhpY_v5XZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go, since its RE2-based `regexp` does not support lookarounds, you need to use *capturing* mechanism with [`regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) function:

```
left := "LEFT_DELIMITER_TEXT_HERE"
right := "RIGHT_DELIMITER_TEXT_HERE"
rx := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)` + regexp.QuoteMeta(left) + `(.*?)` + regexp.QuoteMeta(right))
matches := rx.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
```

Note the use of [`regexp.QuoteMeta`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#QuoteMeta) that automatically escapes all special regex metacharacters in the left- and right-hand delimiters.

The `(?s)` makes `.` match across lines and `(.*?)` captures all between `ABC` and `XYZ` into Group 1.

So, here you can use

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str:= "Movies: A B C Food: 1 2 3"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`Movies:\s*(.*?)\s*Food`)
    matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
        for _, v := range matches {
            fmt.Println(v[1])
        }   
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/8DhhpY_v5XZ). Output: `A B C`.

Comment: I have also written a general [article about extracting strings between two strings with regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions), too, feel free to read if you have a problem approaching your current similar problem.