# webpack error Invalid regular expression: : Invalid group

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

webpack is giving me an error when running npm run build. this is the error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\.)(.*?)(?=\.)/: Invalid group (2391:33)
|                     };
|                 } else if (this.runFlag === true) {
|                     var regex = /(?<=\.)(.*?)(?=\.)/g;
                let redirectRegex =
                    this.hostToRegex.length > 0
                        ? this.hostToRegex.map(x => x.match(regex))
                        : null;
```

Comment: Use capturing, `/\.([^.]*)\./`, get Group 1.

Comment: how do i get group 1? so now I have 
const regex = /\.([^.]*)\./g;
  console.log(this.hostToRegex.map(x => x.match(regex)))
which returns [".abcd."]
but I need to get rid of the dots

Comment: See [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) or [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970).

Comment: now I get ["abcd"] but its an array and i need this as a string

Comment: const regex = /\.([^.]*)\./g;
                    console.log(this.hostToRegex.map(x => regex.exec(x)[1]))

Comment: Then why are you using `g` flag at all if you need the first match? Again, see my answer. `/\.([^.]*)\./.exec(string)[1]`