# Why is my regex not getting all matches in a complemented character class (^)?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please enlighten me, I tried a lot of thing but this doesn't work. I'll give the example I'm getting an error:

```js
let str = `First example (working): {Æ¢ Example phrase 123 áè -*, example Æ¢}
           Second example (not working): {Æ¢ A SuperSlim notebook computer that's light on weight, heavy on features and performance *This .9 thin Notebook Computer weighs in at roughly 3 pounds - which might make you wonder how they cram such great features into that small package *10.4 XGA Active matrix screen with XBRITE display technology *Intel Pentium 300 MHz processor with MMX technology *64 MB of SDRAM is included (expandable to 128 MB maximum) *6.4 GB fixed Hard Drive for Data Storage *Touch Pad with pen operation *One Type II PC card slot with Cardbus Zoomed Video support *External 1.44 MB floppy disk drive *integrated 56K V.90 Data/fax Modem for Internet access *512 KB MultiBank DRAM Cache memory *16-bit, Soundblaster compatible audio *MPEG1 Digital video that supports full screen playback *mono speakers *Built-in microphone *Infrared port *Responsive nearly full-size tactile Keyboard *programmable power key for unattended Email retrieval Please add $30 for shipping. Payment - western union. Æ¢}`

// Regex
console.log(
   str.match(/{Æ¢\s*([^(Æ¢)]*)\s*Æ¢}/g));
```

I am trimming the spaces and getting everything inside the curly brackets followed by "Æ¢" until "Æ¢}"
The result is only the first example in the string, and it doesn't include the second:

```js
> ["{Æ¢ Example phrase 123 áè -*, example Æ¢}"]
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```js
const str = `First example (working): {Æ¢ Example phrase 123 áè -*, example Æ¢}
               Second example (not working): {Æ¢ A SuperSlim notebook computer that's light on weight, heavy on features and performance *This .9 thin Notebook Computer weighs in at roughly 3 pounds - which might make you wonder how they cram such great features into that small package *10.4 XGA Active matrix screen with XBRITE display technology *Intel Pentium 300 MHz processor with MMX technology *64 MB of SDRAM is included (expandable to 128 MB maximum) *6.4 GB fixed Hard Drive for Data Storage *Touch Pad with pen operation *One Type II PC card slot with\n Cardbus Zoomed Video support *External 1.44 MB floppy disk drive *integrated 56K V.90 Data/fax Modem for Internet access *512 KB MultiBank DRAM Cache memory *16-bit, Soundblaster compatible audio *MPEG1 Digital video that supports full screen playback *mono speakers *Built-in microphone *Infrared port *Responsive nearly full-size tactile Keyboard *programmable power key for unattended Email retrieval Please add $30 for shipping. Payment - western union. Æ¢}`

const allMatches = str.matchAll(/{Æ¢\s*(.*?)\s*Æ¢}/gs);

for (let match of allMatches) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

The `s` in the flags `gs` turns on "single-line" or "dotAll" mode so the `.` matches newline characters.

The `?` means match "lazily", i.e. match as few characters as possible before the rest of the pattern can be matched.

When matching globally and using capture groups, `matchAll` or `exec` must be used.

Answer (score -1):

Your second example includes characters that are found in your negated set:

```
[^(Æ¢)]
```

Specifically, the `(` and `)` characters.

If you remove those characters from the regular expression so that your left with:

```
{Æ¢\s*([^Æ¢]*)\s*Æ¢}
```

... then this will match your second example.

Comment: `[^Æ¢]` means any single char other than `Æ` *or* `¢`. Negated character classes do not negate character *sequences*. To negate a char sequence, a tempered greedy token (or its unrolled variant) is required. However, here is just a case of matching strings between two strings.