# Regex - How to match complete paragraph (including new line) using start word and end word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling with regex. I've been trying to find a solution online but I wasn't able to find one.

**Problem:**
I want to select multiple string (with new-line) starting from my `start string` up to my `end string` so I could replace it with a specific word

**Input:** (There is a newline after PRODUCT DESCRIPTION)

```
11111,"testing","PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
Sample Description.",,31.350000,31.35,31
11111,"testing","PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
Sample Description.",,31.350000,31.35,31
11111,"testing","PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
Sample Description.",,31.350000,31.35,31
```

start string = `"PRODUCT DESCRIPTION`

end string = `",`

I'm currently using this regex: `(?=PRODUCT DESCRIPTION)((.|\n)*)(",)`

**Actual Output:**

https://regex101.com/r/S1J7qF/1
A single match was found.

```
["PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
Sample Description.",,31.350000,31.35,31
11111,"testing","PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
Sample Description.",,31.350000,31.35,31
11111,"testing","PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
Sample Description."]
```

**Expected Output:**
3 matches should be found.

```
["PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
    Sample Description.",
 "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
    Sample Description.",
 "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
    Sample Description."]
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970), both explanations and code examples (at the bottom of the post).

Comment: I'm so clumsy, i didn't find this earlier. Thanks! I improved the regex to include newline using this expression `(?=PRODUCT DESCRIPTION)((.|\n)*)(?=",)`

Comment: No, you worsened it a lot. You must use `/PRODUCT DESCRIPTION[^]*?(?=",)/g`

Comment: yes you're right, my solution is still not correct. I updated the question and tried your latest regex it causes an error in [^]

Comment: No, there is no error, if you really use the regex in JavaScript. Again, read [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970). From cover to cover.

Comment: You're right. I'ts working in javascript. You're a live saver!!!

Comment: Great. Also, feel free to see my 3.5-minute youtube regex quickie about [matching strings between two multicharacter strings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGjk0fDK49Y).

Comment: I will! Thank you very much