# RegEx for matching everything between two special characters

Tags: regex

I want to find all characters between 2 special characters. I can't find the solution though because there are new lines that are not included. It's prolly easy, but I can't seem to find the right regex for it.

How do I solve this problem?

The source data is structured like this:

```
\#(.*)\;
```

doesn't include new lines and

```
(?!\#)([\S\s])(?!=\;)
```

doesn't work also.

It selects everything, but doesn't do the group trick...

Source looks like this:

```
#first line of text;
#second line of text;
#third line could easy 
be on a new line;
#forth etc;
#this could (#hi,#hi,#hi) also 
happen though:));
#so.... any idea;
```

any new line starts with `#` and every line ends with `;`

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335593/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your regex,

- You are missing quantifier in your `[\S\s]` due to which it will only match one character.
- Second you need a non-greedy regex so it doesn't match all the lines.

Also, where you wrote this `(?!#)` I guess you meant to write any one character among them, for which you should place it in a character set like this `[?!#]`

You need this regex, where you can capture your text from group1

```
#([\w\W]*?);
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NHuBa/1)**

And like you attempted, if you want your full match to only select the intended text, you can use lookaround.

**[Regex Demo with lookarounds so your full match is intended text only](https://regex101.com/r/0NHuBa/3/)**

Also, writing `[^;]*` (which also matches newlines) is way faster than `.*?` hence you should preferably use this regex,

```
(?<=[?!#])[^;]*(?=;)
```

**[Regex Demo with best performance](https://regex101.com/r/0NHuBa/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify your first regex a little bit so that it looks like this:

```
#([\s\S]*?);
```

- `.` will only match non new line characters. So I replaced it with `[\s\S]` - the set of whitespaces union the set of non-whitespaces - the set of all characters. If your regex engine has the "single line" option, you can turn that on, and `.` will match new lines as well.
- I also made `*` lazy. Otherwise it will just be one whole match that matches all the way to the last `;`. For more info, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).
- You don't need to escape the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either a single line flag `/s` or add whitespace characters `\s` as second alternative to all characters `.`. Also, your `*` quantifier must be lazy/non-greedy, so the whole regex stops at first `;` it founds.

```
#((?:.|\s)*?); or #(.*?);/s
```